# RestKit in android?

Tags: java, android, restlet, restkit

I have used [restkit](http://restkit.org/) framework in ios. Which is very powerful and provides features like caching and all. I am looking whether a similar framework is available in android?

I came across a framework called [restlet](http://www.restlet.org/). But didnt find any samples to work with.

Is there any frameworks out there for the same, for caching data from rest services? Also could some one direct me to good tutorials for restlet in android?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition, there is this first application tutorial covering Restlet edition for Android:
http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.2/introduction/first-steps/first-application

Answer (score 3):

There is a sample to work :

http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.2/introduction/first-steps/first-application

It should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it a framework, but there is a library called [Robospice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) that supports Caching Rest Calls.

Here is the description they posted in their webpage:

> RoboSpice is a modular android library that makes writing asynchronous
>   long running tasks easy. It is specialized in network requests,
>   supports caching and offers REST requests out-of-the box using
>   extension modules

Answer (score 1):

Give [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) a shot. It's easy with plenty of customization available.

It also has [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) that can pair with it.

Also check out this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley). It compares `Retrofit` to `Android AsyncTasks` and `Volley`. As far as speed goes, `Retrofit` wins hands down.

Answer (score 0):

I think the RestTemplate included in Spring for Android is a good solution: http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html

There is a book that provides a tutorial: http://www.packtpub.com/spring-for-android-starter/book

Unlike Restkit which comes with backed in Core Data support, you would still have to find a separate solution if you want to plug your Android Spring REST client into your local sqlite db. It should be possible to use something like http://greendao-orm.com/ in connection with the Spring REST client.