# Equivalent of iOS RestKit for Android

Tags: android, ios, rest, restkit

do you know good librairies that are more or less the equivalent of [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) but for Android ?

I got a small idea but there might be other interesting solutions.

Thx

Comment: check out restlet. and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743747/restkit-in-android

Comment: You can check out the Android volley (from Google). You can download source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley) and tutorial can be found [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library)

Comment: You can find a list of alternatives on the README of RoboSpice : https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/blob/release/README.md

Comment: Give [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) a shot. It looks easy with plenty of customization available.

It also has [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) that can pair with it.

Answer (score 0):

I created and open sourced some code that I based off the idea of RestKit when I saw there was nothing like it for Android.  It can help with Network requests in Android, specifically if you are doing many requests all in the same activity and want to keep things readable.

Its called [Android Network Kit](https://github.com/jamieomatthews/AndroidNetworkKit), and the example app included uses the Spotify API to demonstrate this.  The advantages are that you can keep all the messy networking code in a separate file, but expose a method to parse the response you get back.

It can also help to construct GET or POST requests easily, using GET parameters (GET) , Form encoded parameters (POST) or JSON parameters (POST), by simply supplying an array list of key values.

I don't have any of the Object Mapping that RestKit has, but you could always combine my app with Gson for that. (I plan on including this in the next version of Android Network Kit).

Comment: Object Mapping is one of the majors restkit features.