# Volley vs Aquery vs Android Async HTTP

Tags: android, android-library, android-volley

I am wondering which libraries are best or faster. In my application I am using network request and image caching. I need to know which libraries are the best.

Comment: Use volley. It's by Google, has amazing caching, follows standards, has a great architecture. It's just the best.

Comment: As far as I know Aquery also by google https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: @fish40 it's hosted on Google Code but not made by Google.

Comment: why not write a test application that can use all 3 and compare the actual results?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Aquery for three months now, It's great library and i recommend you to use it,

https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery/releases/tag/0.26.8

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI?tm=6

```
//load an image to an ImageView from network, cache image to file and memory

aq.id(R.id.image1).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");
```

Comment: How does AQuery deal with activity lifecycle? Eg. being destroyed and recreated when rotating or low memory.

Comment: the bad news you must handle this by yourself, the good news it will not crash your app and it will throw a message in the log screen.
for example let's say that you have an activity that load some date but the user has exited before the call back run, Aquary will 
log that you have a null pointer exception and the app will continue to work

Answer (score 0):

AsyncHTTP client has some serious design issues and you need to sometimes override a number of OnSuccess and onFailure methods just to get a response. A number of improvements are currently being made. On the other hand Volley seem to be having memory leak issues: check this post [volley-slow-memory-leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472809/volley-slow-and-causing-memory-leak). However, I have used it now for few weeks, it seem like a better option that and I have not experienced any memory leaks myself. What is also important to note is that Volley has better response times compared to Asynchttp, at least from the few tests that I have done

Comment: There is no memory leak

Comment: @ItaiHanski - I have just tested Volley. No memory leaks [yet]. Seem to be more efficient than Android Async HTTP.

Comment: Then perhaps you should edit your post as to not create a false impression.

Comment: @ItaiHanski look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley/18863395#18863395