# Volley slow and causing memory leak

Tags: android, android-volley

In my project, I am using volley to download a JSON stream which I parse and show in a listview.  I use the following method to load my data:

```
private void loadEventData(int year, final int month) {

    // get volley request queue
    requestQueue = cpcApplication.getRequestQueue(getActivity());

    String url = "****************?year=" + year
            + "&month=" + month;

    pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading Events", "Retrieving Data from Server");
    pd.setCancelable(true);

    JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            Log.i(TAG, response.toString());

            // parse the incoming response
            parseJson(response, month);

            // notify the listview that the data set has changed
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // set the listview at the top position
            listView.setSelection(current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            // dismiss the ProgressDialog
            pd.dismiss();

        }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            error.printStackTrace();

            // cancel the progress dialog
            pd.dismiss();

            // let the user know that a network connection is not available
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot communicate with server.  Check network connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });

    // add the network request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jr);

}
```

The first call to this method works beautifully.  In the second call, I get a timeout error.  When I use the following command:

```
jr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            2500, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

to increase the amount of time for the request, the request takes over 30 seconds and produces the following log output:

```
10-19 20:53:19.746: D/Volley(17523): [2786] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://************ 0x63ea5535 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=41769], [size=5467846], [rc=200], [retryCount=2]
10-19 20:53:19.796: D/dalvikvm(17523): GC_CONCURRENT freed 7462K, 26% free 24424K/33000K, paused 6ms+4ms, total 56ms
10-19 20:53:19.796: D/dalvikvm(17523): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 51ms
10-19 20:53:19.826: I/dalvikvm-heap(17523): Grow heap (frag case) to 35.123MB for 10935708-byte allocation
10-19 20:53:19.857: D/dalvikvm(17523): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 20% free 35100K/43680K, paused 23ms, total 28ms
10-19 20:53:19.917: D/dalvikvm(17523): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2018K, 19% free 35816K/43680K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 60ms
10-19 20:53:20.007: D/dalvikvm(17523): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4874K, 15% free 37226K/43680K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 27ms
10-19 20:53:20.007: D/dalvikvm(17523): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 24ms
10-19 20:53:20.067: D/dalvikvm(17523): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5037K, 15% free 38601K/44900K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
10-19 20:53:20.117: D/dalvikvm(17523): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4680K, 14% free 40045K/46564K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
10-19 20:53:20.177: D/dalvikvm(17523): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5576K, 14% free 41572K/48272K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
10-19 20:53:20.227: D/dalvikvm(17523): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6133K, 15% free 43406K/50548K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
10-19 20:53:20.287: D/dalvikvm(17523): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6486K, 15% free 45029K/52428K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 24ms
10-19 20:53:20.287: D/dalvikvm(17523): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
10-19 20:53:20.407: D/Volley(17523): [1] Request.finish: 42553 ms: [ ] http://****** 0x63ea5535 NORMAL 1
```

When I perform the same request in a browser, it takes only several seconds.  Why the delay and incredible memory consumption?

Comment: I had some trouble with *Volley* too - in particular some caching inconsistencies. Have you had a look at [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidquery)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every call to the method you create a new `RequestQueue` which is not a recommended approach. You should create one `RequestQueue`, probably a publicly visible singleton that is initialized once when the app is created.

Try moving the `RequestQueue` outside and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks!  It's still slow which leads me to examine the server side, but it's tolerable.  I moved the requestQueue line into the onCreate of the Fragment and added a singleton to manage it.  Much appreciated!

Comment: You should not store activity references in a static variable. That's the most common cause of memory leak. Here's a blog post on [Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

Comment: Point taken. You can make it a singleton then, the main idea is that it is shared throughout the app.

Comment: @ItaiHanski you mean we need to initialize the RequestQueue in Application class and use same object in rest od the activities, fragments ?

Answer (score 2):

i have some problem with:

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
```

it caused the first request at startup to take awfully long time in some phones.
i changed it to:

```
Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024);
Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
mRequestQueue.start();
```

That solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying explain with few code (already Itai is explained in brief)

Below code explains how to use the global request queue for Volley with a singleton instance of the application class for easy access in other places and make the code more memory efficient!.

> public class ApplicationController extends Application {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Log or request TAG
>  */
> public static final String TAG = "VolleyPatterns";
>
> /**
>  * Global request queue for Volley
>  */
> private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
>
> /**
>  * A singleton instance of the application class for easy access in other places
>  */
> private static ApplicationController sInstance;
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate() {
>     super.onCreate();
>
>     // initialize the singleton
>     sInstance = this;
> }
>
> /**
>  * @return ApplicationController singleton instance
>  */
> public static synchronized ApplicationController getInstance() {
>     return sInstance;
> }
>
> /**
>  * @return The Volley Request queue, the queue will be created if it is null
>  */
> public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
>     // lazy initialize the request queue, the queue instance will be
>     // created when it is accessed for the first time
>     if (mRequestQueue == null) {
>         mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
>     }
>
>     return mRequestQueue;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Adds the specified request to the global queue, if tag is specified
>  * then it is used else Default TAG is used.
>  * 
>  * @param req
>  * @param tag
>  */
> public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
>     // set the default tag if tag is empty
>     req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
>
>     VolleyLog.d("Adding request to queue: %s", req.getUrl());
>
>     getRequestQueue().add(req);
> }
>
> /**
>  * Adds the specified request to the global queue using the Default TAG.
>  * 
>  * @param req
>  * @param tag
>  */
> public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
>     // set the default tag if tag is empty
>     req.setTag(TAG);
>
>     getRequestQueue().add(req);
> }
>
> /**
>  * Cancels all pending requests by the specified TAG, it is important
>  * to specify a TAG so that the pending/ongoing requests can be cancelled.
>  * 
>  * @param tag
>  */
> public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
>     if (mRequestQueue != null) {
>         mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
>     }
> } }
> ```

for the complete implementation ref this [blog](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)

Credits: Arnab Chakraborty