# Android HTTP to C# Server

Tags: c#, android, http

Using HTTP I want to send simple string data through android to a C# .NET server. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley) suggests using OKHTTP which looks great, but I'm not sure how this would talk to a C# server as I will need a 'connection' where I can send data back to the android phone.

OKHTTP seems to manage drops in connection elegantly according to the [website](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), which is fantastic because I need this kind of persistance, but I'm not sure how I would implement the C# side.

Does anyone know a method of accomplishing this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a C# server? Do you mean OWIN? http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana

Comment: No, not a web application server. Just a desktop C# .NET service that listens for HTTP requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as though you want to do a normal [HTTP POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) to your server. It's the same thing that would happen when you fill out a form on a web-page and submit the data to a server. If it's a normal kind of webserver it should have full support for receiving a POST and returning a response as well. Are you writing the .NET web service as well?

As for client side technology to use: OkHTTP is a greaty drop-in class for making HTTP requests to a server, but if you plan to do many of them you should also look into wrapping the actual HTTP client into an API that takes care of asynchronous callbacks and things like that. You don't want to be doing HTTP requests on the UI thread and it's boring and error prone to wrap all such calls in [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or similar. Take a look at [AndroidAsyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/):

"An asynchronous callback-based Http client for Android built on top of Apache’s HttpClient libraries. All requests are made outside of your app’s main UI thread, but any callback logic will be executed on the same thread as the callback was created using Android’s Handler message passing."

(As a sidenote AndroidAsyncHttpClient might get support for using OkHTTP instead of the default Apache HttpClient)

POSTing to a server is as simple as this:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("A_KEY_TO_IDENTIFY_YOUR_STRING", "THE_STRING_YOU_WANT_TO_SEND");

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post("http://www.yourserver.com", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        // handle your response from the server here
        System.out.println(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: fantastic! This is exactly what I was looking for, and it has timeout, asynchronous and retry functionality built in which makes it a whole lot easier to use