# How to prevent a Fragment from being added when an Activity is closing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-service, android-handler

I am creating an `Activity` which communicates with a `Service` to download some data from internet via `POST` method. To do this, I use `Messenger`. Here is my code to make it clearer for you:

My `onCreated()` method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);

    CommentsHandler commentsHandler = new CommentsHandler(this, savedInstanceState);
    Messenger messenger = new Messenger(commentsHandler);

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, WindowService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("messenger", messenger);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("state", 888);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("number", getIntent().getStringExtra("number"));
    startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

The code in my `Service`'s thread to post the result data to the `Activity` via the `Messenger` object:

```
    /** ... **/
    Messenger messenger = intent.getParcelableExtra("messenger");
    /** ... **/
    Message resultMsg = this.obtainMessage();
    resultMsg.obj = jParser.getArrayList(); //This is an ArrayList of my downloaded data.
    messenger.send(resultMsg);
```

The code in the `Activity` to handle the `Message` from the `Service`:

```
public static class CommentsHandler extends Handler {
    Bundle mSavedInstanceState;
    ActionBarActivity activity;

    public CommentsHandler(Activity a, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        activity = (ActionBarActivity) a;
        mSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        comments = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) msg.obj;
        if (mSavedInstanceState == null && msg.arg1 != 793) {
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new CommentsFragment()).commit();
        } else if (msg.arg1 == 793) { //793 is my preferred code to determine
                                      //if the internet connection could not be
                                      //established when the Service was trying
                                      //to download the data.
            activity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: if I open the `Activity` and close it before the data is downloaded, this code `.add(R.id.container, new CommentsFragment()).commit();` gives me the error `Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`, because this code only gets executed after the data in my `Service` is processed and sent via the `Messenger` object, but at that time the `Activity` is already closed by the user so the `Fragment` cannot be added. How to solve this issue? How to check if the `Activity` is not closed/being closed before adding the `Fragment`? Or, better, how to stop the thread in which that code is running on `Activity`'s `onDestroy()` method so it doesn't get executed if the `Activity` is closed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest change would be to have a boolean field in the Activity, setting it to true in `onResume()` and to false in `onPause()`, and check its value in `handleMessage()` (i.e. ignore the message if the flag is currently false).

Another option, instead of using Messenger and `handleMessage()`, do this with a `BroadcastReceiver`. Register the receiver in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`. That way the broadcast from the service will be simply ignored.

Both solutions are basically the same, anyway, but broadcasts are somewhat "higher level".

This assumes that you're not interested in the Service's result if the activity is paused. If you are (for example, if you switch out of the application and back in, and you need to display the update) then you should put the received data in a field and process it on the following `onResume()`.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much! But if I choose the simplest way (the boolean method you described above), would my code be worse or less appropriate than with the `BroadcastReceiver` implementation?

Comment: @Salivan Not at all. I just wanted to point out that `LocalBroadcastManager` is very well suited for service->activity communication within an application

Answer (score 3):

In your activity, you should create a boolean to check if the activity is visible or not:

```
public ActionBarActivity extends Activity {
  private boolean isActivityVisible = false;

  @Override
  protected void onResume(){
     isActivityVisible = true;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause(){
     isActivityVisible = false;
  }

  public boolean isVisible(){
     return this.isActivityVisible;
  }
}
```

And then you modify your Handler class definition:

```
public static class CommentsHandler extends Handler {
Bundle mSavedInstanceState;
ActionBarActivity activity;

public CommentsHandler(Activity a, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    activity = (ActionBarActivity) a;
    mSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // here you check if your activity is no longer visible and then break up
    if(activity == null || !activity.isVisible())
        return;

    comments = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) msg.obj;
    if (mSavedInstanceState == null && msg.arg1 != 793) {
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new CommentsFragment()).commit();
    } else if (msg.arg1 == 793) { //793 is my preferred code to determine
                                  //if the internet connection could not be
                                  //established when the Service was trying
                                  //to download the data.
        activity.finish();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Great and very simple solution, but @matiash's answer was more comprehensive with more reasonable explanations. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your way of doing this is different than how I would handle it but using what you have I would make these adjustments:

```
public static class CommentsHandler extends Handler {
    Bundle mSavedInstanceState;
    ActionBarActivity activity;

    public CommentsHandler(Activity a, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        activity = (ActionBarActivity) a;
        mSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    }

    public void setActivity(Activity a){
        activity = a;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(activity == null){
            return;
        }
        comments = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) msg.obj;
        if (mSavedInstanceState == null && msg.arg1 != 793) {
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new CommentsFragment()).commit();
        } else if (msg.arg1 == 793) { //793 is my preferred code to determine
                                      //if the internet connection could not be
                                      //established when the Service was trying
                                      //to download the data.
            activity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would use your activities onPause()/onResume() methods to like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    commentsHandler.setActivity(null);  
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    commentsHandler.setActivity(this);  
}
```

Comment: Cool answer! I like your logic pretty much but that's a pitty that you didn't share with me the way you would do it. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Well I do not know the full scope of your project so the way I would do it may change based on that but I would use a library like one mentioned in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know the complexity of implementing this library, but I guess that I don't have to use the whole library just to download a couple of JASON strings. Thank you very much anyway.