# Support a varying object data type with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Below is a description of the data structure of the data I need the Android app to pass to the REST API in JSON form. Of particular note is the "response" field, which varies in type. Sometimes it is a boolean, sometimes an integer, or it can be a string or an array of integers. For various reasons the server API cannot easily be changed so I have to support it as is.

How can I customise my Retrofit use to cater to a field that varies in data type like this? I've previously written type adapters for Retrofit's rest adapter and that works great for handling responses, but what is the equivalent of a type adapter for requests?

```
array(
        array(
                question_id => 1,
                route_id => 1,
                response => true,
                timestamp => ‘2014-01-01 20:01:01'
        ),
        array(
                question_id => 2,
                route_id => 1,
                response => ’this is a string',
                timestamp => ‘2014-01-01 20:01:01'
        ),
        array(
                question_id => 3,
                route_id => 1,
                response => 1,
                timestamp => ‘2014-01-01 20:01:01'
        ),
        array(
                question_id => 4,
                route_id => 1,
                response => array(
                        1234,
                        178,
                        109
                ),
                timestamp => ‘2014-01-01 20:01:01'
        ),
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle Dynamic JSON in Retrofit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245/how-to-handle-dynamic-json-in-retrofit)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is supremely easy. If Retrofit is passed objects of type Object within the model class, it intelligently converts them to the right JSON field type.

```
public class MyModel {

    // Renders to JSON as boolean, int, String etc depending on the underlying class
    public Object response; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply your own json converter that would handle it internally. [How to handle Dynamic JSON in Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245/how-to-handle-dynamic-json-in-retrofit)