# Handle unknown REST/JSON return type

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

We are using Retrofit library v1.9.0 to retrieve webservices from our servers using REST calls.

Problem is, I **must** specify the return type of every single object in the webservice, otherwise an exception is thrown. Here's an example :

```
serviceTest.testWebservice(new Callback<MessageFromWebservice>() {
            @Override
            public void success(MessageFromWebservice message, Response response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Test returned : " + message.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Test error : " + retrofitError.toString());
            }
        });
```

Where my callback is

```
class MessageFromWebservice{
private List<Product> products;
}
```

So, my Android app's must retrieve only some products : the JSON HAS TO BE

```
"{products: [
{label="Product1", price="12"},
{label="Product2", price="21"}
]}"
```

Now, my server could send me only ONE product, resulting JSON would be an Object Product instead of a Product array.

```
"{products:{label="Product1", price="12"}}"
```

Whenever this happens, Retrofit throws an Exception, application crashes.

I don't understand why Retrofit can't handle unknown return type from server (single Object or Array in the same variable).

Error is as follow, if my Class wants a List, and a single Product is returned by the webservice.

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 14 path $.products
```

there's this solution :
[How to handle Dynamic JSON in Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245/how-to-handle-dynamic-json-in-retrofit?answertab=votes#tab-top)

but it seems way too complicated not to be already included in the Retrofit library...

Comment: You can use [Response](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/index.html) as return type. You can get body from `Response` using `getBody` method.

Comment: please paste crash logcat.

Comment: @ Tauqir : Logcat edited in question. @Ziem : So I can read the InputStream and instanciate either JSONObject or JSONArray ? Then I don't need to use Retrofit library but just create my URLConnection.openConnection() and read the stream from that ?

Comment: Retrofit is HTTP client and it is up to you how you will parse your data. If you don't like solution with `Response` class you can use [JsonDeserialize](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html). [Here](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/) you can find example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [deserializer](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) for your Gson converter.  The basic idea is to intercept the deserialization after the response has been converted to a Json tree, but before it is convert to your objects.  In the deserializer, check the `products` field to see if it is an array or single object and deserialize as appropriate.  Here is a sketch of how it would look for your object above.

```
public class MessageSerializer implements JsonDeserializer<MessageFromWebservice> {

    @Override
    public  MessageFromWebservice deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        MessageFromWebservice message = new MessageFromWebservice();
        if(json.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
            if(jsonObject.has("products")) {
                JsonElement products = jsonObject.get("products");
                if(products.isJsonArray()) {
                    Type productListType = new TypeToken<List<Product>>(){}.getType();
                    message.products = context.deserialize(products, productListType);
                } else {
                    message.products = new ArrayList<Product>(1);
                    Product product = context.deserialize(products, Product.class);
                    message.products.add(product);
                }
            }
            return message;
         } else {
            // top level is supposed to be an object
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
}
```

then you can create a custom Gson instance and register the above adapter --

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(MessageFromWebservice.class, new MessageSerializer())
                .create();
```

and add a call to `setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))` in your `RestAdapter` builder.  Like --

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                //... other options
                .build();
```