# Convert to JSONObject / JSONArray with Retrofit v2.0.0-beta1

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am currently in the process of upgrading to Retrofit v.2.0.0-beta1 and in [the docs](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) it says:

> By default, Retrofit can only deserialize HTTP bodies into OkHttp's ResponseBody type and it can only accept its RequestBody type for @Body.
>
> Converters can be added to support other types. Six sibling modules adapt popular serialization libraries for your convenience.

How exactly do I add a GSON converter so instead of `RequestBody` I receive `GSON.JsonObject` or `GSON.JsonArray` for responses with `Content-type: application/json`?

My initialization code looks like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

client.interceptors().add(new AuthInterceptor(authState));
client.interceptors().add(new LoggingInterceptor());

restClient = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(client)
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build()
        .create(RestClient.class);
```

Comment: Why do you want to receive Gson wrapper objects instead of POJOs?

Comment: Because I would prefer to use them like a map. There are many different endpoints in the API I'm dealing with, resulting in a wide range of different types. Coming from more dynamic languages as Java, this seems to create more hassle than good to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle Dynamic JSON in Retrofit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245/how-to-handle-dynamic-json-in-retrofit)

Comment: I hope that question will help you.

Comment: In retrofit 2, each call is a separate object and it is typed (YES!!) so you can specify what type of response object for each different endpoints.  I updated with the example of how to specify type for a specific call.  So instead of you get generic map and do mapping by yourself, retrofit already do that for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Retrofit2, it will not come with a default converter so you need to explicitly add a converter.

You can add like this.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

And you can get a mapped object by either

```
Call<MyObject> call = myService.callMyService();
Response<MyObject> response = call.execute();
MyObject mappedObj = response.body();
```

or

```
Call<MyObject> call = myService.callMyService();
call.enqueue(new Callback<MyObject>() {
    @Override void onResponse(Response response) {
        MyObject mappedObj = response.body();
    }

    @Override void failure(Throwable throwable) {}
});
```

Also add dependencies
    `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'`

Reference: https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/simple-http-with-retrofit-2-droidcon-nyc-2015