# how to handle type boolean and object in retrofit response?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

i m getting response from server and inside response there is object and object contains another arrayofobjects and an individual object  contains object (this object is sometimes returning me object and sometimes server is sending me false)  so in case of false i m getting error **RetrofitError:com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BOOLEAN at line 1 column 9774**

how can i resolve this  issue ?

```
public class NotificationResponse {

    private UserNotificaions User_Notificaions;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}
public class UserNotificaions {
 private List<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
    private Pager pager;
    private Integer nextPage;
    private Integer prePage;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}
public class Record{
private String name;
private String title;
private String profile_image;
private String id;
private String uid;
private String notification_type_id;

private String bid;
private String is_read;
private String total_notifications;
private BcastObj bcast_obj;
    private User user_obj;
}
public class BcastObj {
    private String bid;
    private String name;
    private String message;
    private String tags;
}
public class User
{

    private String total;

    private String broadcast_comment_id;

    private String bid;
}
```

[SERVER response](http://pastie.org/10418603#5,9,13-15,18,24,88,90,101-102,105,108-109,120,143,145,484,530,533,537,608)  please take a look into  "user_obj" and bcast_obj" in some conduitions server is sending me false in bcast_obj" while in some its not sending me bcast_obj" and only sending me user_obj  so how to handle these two parts .... the major issue is once server is sending me  **false** in **user_obj**

HERE is the " false " reciving in an object

```
 {
            "name": null,
            "title": "NewBroadcastcreated",
            "message": "abcihascreatednewbroadcast.",
            "full_name": "abci",
            "profile_thumb": "",
            "profile_image": "",
            "id": "C24-F5C8-DD24-4FF6-44978782082F",
            "uid": "4E8A0-F3DD-C41D-4105-6443222CAB3C",
            "notification_type_id": "2",
            "is_created": "1420",
            "sender_id": "F492B0-FB8C-8CD8-4C51-D77BEC987A78",
            "type": "general",
            "bid": "E1D-4426-B095-5F55-18A120F8C9D6",
            "is_read": "1",
            "is_notify_popup": "0",
            "total_notifications": "937",
            "bcast_obj": false
        }
```

Comment: Add json response here.

Comment: add the POJO class too

Comment: @Bhargav pls see now i added response and class both

Comment: @PankajKumar  pls check i added both response and class

Comment: also attach the response of the server when it sends false in user_obj, because the thing while trying to parse user_obj gson is expecting an object not a boolean, and that seems to be the error you are getting

Comment: @Bhargav  this is not the issue i  just eliminate getters and setter for posting here so that any one can understand code easily the big issue is not of getters and setters i have already made in my class

Comment: alright i have deleted that comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89579/discussion-between-erum-and-bhargav).

Comment: @Bhargav  it cannot be correct from server side how will i handle from android  side ?

Comment: catch this specific exception query the exception message to see if it matches the message you expect then assign null to bcast_obj

Comment: @Bhargav  but i have to change type of bcast_obj like if it matches the exception then i want to put false instead of object null ?

Comment: where will i catch exception query ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a custom converter that detects if it is a boolean or an json-object. You might want to have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28576252/322642

Comment: i already looked into the link but i m not getting how to use this ?

Answer (score 1):

server has to be consistent if it wants bcast_obj to be object then it should be sent as a proper json object (i.e starting and ending with braces) shouldn't be sent as boolean as it will completely change the signature of your object.

Comment: +1 @Erum If you want to specify that there is no `bcast_obj` in a particular response, use `null` instead of `false`

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution, but you may replace BcastObj with JsonElement as a data type for the response bcast_obj that returns either as an Object or as a boolean. JsonElement class is the parent class for both JsonObject and JsonPrimitive. Here is an example:

```
if (response.body().getBcastObj().getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString().equals("stringValue"))
    // write code for the first case when bcast_obj returns as an Object
else if (!response.body().getBcastObj().getAsBoolean())
    // write code for the second case when bcast_obj returns as a boolean false
```

You may also consider converting bcast_obj (after making its data type as JsonElement instead of BcastObj) to string and check if it contains specific data or just contains a boolean value. The conversion can be made as following:

```
String bcast_objString = new Gson().toJson(bcast_obj);
```