# Retrofit - Download csv file from server in android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to download a file from server using retrofit. Using HttpLoggingInterceptor I tried logging what is happening. I can find the file name. But the response body is empty.

I am new to using retrofit. can some one point me out in the right direction on where I am going wrong

**Retrofit Client Interface:**

```
public interface DownloadTransactions {

@Streaming
@GET("common/frontend/member/download.aspx")
Call<Void> getBalancesAndTransactions(@Header("Cookie") String header);
```

}

**Java call:**

```
void downloadData() {

    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        client.addInterceptor(logging);
    }


    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder();
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client.build())
            .baseUrl("https://" + getString(R.string.root_url))
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    DownloadTransactions downloadTransactions = retrofit.create(DownloadTransactions.class);
    Call<Void> call = downloadTransactions.getBalancesAndTransactions(CommsManager.getInstance().getASPSessionId());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, retrofit2.Response<Void> response) {
            Log.v(TAG, "success transactions: --------" + response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v(TAG, "failure transactions: --------");
        }
    });


}
```

**Response in log:**

```
<-- 200 OK https://xxxxx.com/common/xxx/member/download.aspx (387ms)
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: private
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-16
D/OkHttp: Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Account_Summary_8978_04062018_142921.csv
D/OkHttp: X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
D/OkHttp: Date: Mon, 04 Jun 2018 13:29:21 GMT
D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 446900
D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: xxx; path=/; Httponly; Secure
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (binary 446900-byte body omitted)


D/Accounts Overview: success transactions: --------
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=xxx}
```

Comment: Try this https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-download-files-from-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the response body is empty.

Retrofit determines the type of response with the return type of the methods defined in your API interface.

The return type of `getBalancesAndTransactions`is `Void` which means nothing.

Solution : Define your customise POJO class and replace `Void` with `POJO

or Just for testing purpose, you can use `Object` which can handle any type of response but you will have to use casting for specific operation

e.g

```
@Streaming
@GET("common/frontend/member/download.aspx")
Call<Object> getBalancesAndTransactions(@Header("Cookie") String header);
```

References :

[How can we handle different response type with Retrofit 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583308/how-can-we-handle-different-response-type-with-retrofit-2)

[Using Retrofit in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500036/using-retrofit-in-android)

Comment: True. I missed it, I replaced Void return type with ResponseBody. And it works