# Handling variable JSON with Retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am getting data from backend (using Retrofit), one of whose key contains a JSON object as its value. I have written the following class structure for this object:

```
public class NotificationData {
    @SerializedName("photo_pk")
    @Expose
    private int photoPk;
    @SerializedName("gallery_pk")
    @Expose
    private int galleryPk;
    @SerializedName("user_pk")
    @Expose
    private int userPk;
}
```

The problem is that the value of this object can be `null` or, if it isn't `null`, it can contain either the field `photo_pk` or `gallery_pk` or may be `gallery_pk` and `user_pk`. If the backend would have been sending all the fields and providing values for fields which exist and `null` for others, it would have worked perfectly. But since some fields are coming and some are not, depending on the situation, I want the values that are coming from backend to be matched properly and for those fields, which are not coming from backend, I want them to be `null` or some other default value. How can I achieve that?

Here is the sample JSON

```
{  
    'display':{  
        'image':'https://kdfnvdfkdvd',
        'title':'fkfjkfdvfldvmdflv',
        'large_text':'bvfdkvkdfv',
        'icon':'something.jpg',
        'image_format':'SQUARE'
    },
    'data':{  
        'image_pk':9
    },
    'notif_id':8,
    'screen':'IMAGE',
    'priority':0,
    'time':'2016-02-06 15:22:33',
    is_read:False
}
```

The field that I am referring is data. It contains variable JSON.

Comment: can you share sample json that you are getting after api call

Comment: @ankitaggarwal I have edited the question. Have a look.

Comment: Try to pass this `gson` instance to Retrofit. `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Integer` instead of `int`. In this case your variable could be null.

```
public class NotificationData {
    @SerializedName("photo_pk")
    @Expose
    private Integer photoPk;
    @SerializedName("gallery_pk")
    @Expose
    private Integer galleryPk;
    @SerializedName("user_pk")
    @Expose
    private Integer userPk;
}
```

Comment: thanks, let me try, if it works, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity there are multiple sollutions.

1. Change int to Integer
2. Try to parse the JSON in a converter:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/28576252/2429753