# GSON Parsing - Same key with different type

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am new in gson parsing. I have response

```
{"data":[23, "Nithinlal P.A"]}
```

Sometimes I got the response as

```
{"data":false}
```

I am using Retrofit 2 Http client library.So I got error while getting the response like this.How I can overcome this issue.

Comment: this looks for Retrofit-1 , not sure if this will work to Retrofit-2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245/how-to-handle-dynamic-json-in-retrofit

Answer (score 1):

If you know what type of data a given request will return, you can use the following approach:

Set the data field to a generic type `T` in your `APIResponse` object e.g.

```
public class APIResponse<T>{
  private T data;
  public T getData();
}
```

Then, for the first response, you should create a class called User

```
class User{
   private long id;
   private String name;
}
```

and add a method to your retrofit api:

```
@GET("/api/user")    
void getUser(Callback< APIResponse <User>> callback);
```

For the second response, you would add the method

```
@GET("/api/status")
void getStatus(Callback< APIResponse <Boolean>> callback);
```

**NOTE**
At the moment, your first response returns an array with inconsistent types. E.g. the first item is an integer (23) and the second item is a string ("Nithinlal P.A")
Your first response should be a JSON object.

Comment: i don't think that OP is able to determine when it will be object or not, i think it's based on the request result (unpredictable)

Comment: @W.K.S I  can't predit the which type of response receive. So How can I call this

Comment: @Nithinlal: Yazan has linked an answer for that scenario in his comment