# Android Parsing Same variable object name in retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, gson

I had seen many examples regarding retrofit.And I had Done too most of like listview but this is something new which I am not finding easily.I am using retrofit2.Here it has same name **details** first is simple object and other have nested object and I am bit confuse how to parse it.It is alogin form First it checks details if it is one then it goes further.

```
[
 {
"title": "success",
"details": "1"
},
{
"title": "data",
"details": {
  "EMPLOYEE_ID": 5,
  "FIRST_NAME": "ABHISHEK",
  "LAST_NAME": "BARDOLIA"

  }
 }
]
```

Here is the Interface used in login purpose.

```
  public interface LoginInterface {
  @GET("Login")
  Call<List<ClsLogin>> Login(@Query("username") String username
        , @Query("password") String password
        , @Query("imei") String imei);
}
```

Model Class:
     public class ClsLogin {

```
@SerializedName("title")
String title;

@SerializedName("details")
String details;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}

public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
 }
}
```

Response Code:

```
public static void login(final LoginCallback logincallback, ClsLogin ObjLogin) {
    LoginInterface apiLoginService = ApiClient.getClient().create(LoginInterface.class);

    Call<List<ClsLogin>> call = apiLoginService.Login(
            ObjLogin.getUsername(),
            ObjLogin.getPassword(),
            ObjLogin.getImei());
    Log.e("response", String.valueOf(call.request().url()));


call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ClsLogin>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<ClsLogin>> call, Response<List<ClsLogin>> response) {
        Log.e("response", "onResponse ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<ClsLogin>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("response", t.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
});


}
```

Comment: use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate Model class for your response

Comment: how to use this @Divyesh?

Comment: first copy your json and paste in above site, then select JSON and GSON from right side menu and click on Preview

Comment: @Divyesh Thanks bro it got very simple to make a model class for response but now how can we check first details and then run second detail thing?

Comment: i think you need to change above parameter name like message and msgcode

Comment: yeah thats true @divyesh bhai i will change it later and thank you for this bt now main problem is i need to check first detail which is 1 and then nested details how to do it??

Comment: wait some time i will check it.

Comment: have you got some solution regarding this issue??

Comment: no, i found that you have to change parameter name of your json

Comment: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 4 column 17 path $[0].details this error is coming bro... @divyesh bhai

Comment: check you JSON, make sure it is start with {

Comment: no bro it starts with [ this only...

Comment: you used GSON to prase json?

Comment: Url is getting perfect but response is not getting....it directly goes to onfailure.

Comment: you used Call<List<ClsLogin>> or else?

Comment: Source type:JSON,Annotation style:Gson

Comment: post changes JSON and retrofit Client code

Comment: Exactly you can see it in question and again rechecked same was there..

Comment: Edited brother...

Comment: "LAST_NAME": "BARDOLIA",  this lines is invalid format. Remove , from last

Comment: it was mistake as i had deleted further details now  it is ok ....

Comment: you get error because in first Object, details is in String Format and in second it is JSON OBJECT. So retrofit can not parse due to mismatch

Comment: if you do this: {
    "title": "success",
    "details": {
      
    }
  }, then it work

Comment: yeah same doubt so whats the solution man?

Comment: But okhttp is taking this property why retrofit not taking??

Comment: you should rearrage your json format: {
  "message": "Success",
  "msgcode": "0",
  "list": [
    {
      "EMPLOYEE_ID": 5,
      "FIRST_NAME": "ABHISHEK",
      "LAST_NAME": "BARDOLIA"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Is there any other solution to deal with this? Coz it will change in all other previous projects so...

Comment: i don't know any solution now. Maybe some one post any answer

Comment: Btw Thank you very much...it was much enough solution for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28576252/6756514

Comment: Quite difficult to understand better to change the properties...Thanks man for help... @divyesh bhai.

Comment: try other way. if i find solution I let you know

Comment: @divyesh bro [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717236/incomplete-response-in-retrofit-when-there-is-null) please solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see how `GsonConverterFactory` parsing data:

```
  @Override
  public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations,
  Retrofit retrofit) {
     TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(type));
     return new GsonResponseBodyConverter<>(adapter);
}
```

how `GsonResponseBodyConverter` works:

```
    @Override public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
    try {
      return adapter.fromJson(value.charStream());
    } finally {
      value.close();
    }
  }
```

so you can write your own ResponseBodyConverter to differentiate between data and the status code,you just have to override the convert method.
because,GsonConverterFactory and GsonRequestBodyConverter are finnal class,you should copy them in your project.And you should code your Custom GsonResponseBodyConverter:

```
 final class CusGsonResponseBodyConverter<T> implements Converter<ResponseBody, T> {
    private final TypeAdapter<T> adapter;
    private final Gson gson;

    CusGsonResponseBodyConverter(TypeAdapter<T> adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.gson = new Gson();
    }

    @Override
    public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        //get the response string data
        String response = value.string();

        //in there,you can check your data
        // for exp,you can catch the exception and return the entity with error flag
        //or just return the gson entity,like this:
        MediaType contentType = value.contentType();
        Charset charset = contentType != null ? contentType.charset(UTF_8) : UTF_8;
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes());
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset);
        JsonReader jsonReader = gson.newJsonReader(reader);

        try {
            return adapter.read(jsonReader);
        } finally {
            value.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate and show me small demo example of given question?