# JSON key some time string and some time list value android retrofit

Tags: java, android, json

Response 1:

```
               {
                    "id": "85",
                    "email": "jack@test.com",
                    "profession": [
                        {
                            "category_id": "1",
                            "name": "ARTIST"
                        }
                    ],
                    "genre": [
                        {
                            "category_id": "3",
                            "name": "ROCK"
                        }
                    ],
                    "instruments": "No list has found",
               }
```

Response 2:

```
  {
    "id": "85",
    "email": "jack@test.com",
    "profession": [{
        "category_id": "1",
        "name": "ARTIST"
    }],
    "genre": [{
        "category_id": "3",
        "name": "ROCK"
    }],
    "instruments": [{
        "category_id": "3",
        "name": "ROCK"
    }],
  }
```

In first response instruments key have a String value, In second response instruments have a array. create the pojo class for second response but some times i got first response also it move OnFailure . how can i handle in Retrofit.

Comment: my question is why the response is changing?

Comment: Any network API do not have anything to do with response except parsing  AFAIK . Its your Server which is building this response.

Comment: @ChiragRaval it's not necessary actually

Comment: You can solve this by handling dynamic response in retrofit  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245/how-to-handle-dynamic-json-in-retrofit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245/how-to-handle-dynamic-json-in-retrofit

Comment: @PareshMayani Thanks for the addressing.

Answer (score 1):

Different types of json objects is not possible to parse in single request/response. So you should use this on following way.

if your `instruments` object is empty means don't set string like `"No list has found"`, Instead of you should send like  `"instruments": []`,

now `instruments` is list coming but **size is 0(zero)**, that means there is no data, like  **"No list has found"**

so your response should be like this

```
{
    "id": "85",
    "email": "jack@test.com",
    "profession": [{
        "category_id": "1",
        "name": "ARTIST"
    }],
    "genre": [{
        "category_id": "3",
        "name": "ROCK"
    }],
    "instruments": [],
  "other": [{
        "category_id": "4",
        "name": "Test"
    }],
  }
```

Validate the list size in local and process your way..

Hope this will help you :)...

Comment: You could just define `Object instruments`. Then cast to a list or string. Therefore, it's possible, but brittle code