# Implementing a custom GsonCoverterFactory/Deserializer for dynamic types

Tags: android, json, gson, json-deserialization

How do I implement a custom GsonConverterFactor or a JsonDeserializer for types that have dynamic values?

For example:

If Tags object has content, it looks like this:

```
"tags": [
                {
                    "content_id": "13",
                    "tag_id": "3",
                    "created": "2018-03-26 11:09:08",
                    "tag_name": "FICTION"
                },
                {
                    "content_id": "13",
                    "tag_id": "7",
                    "created": "2018-03-26 11:09:08",
                    "tag_name": "JUVENILE FICTION"
                }
            ]
```

However, if it is empty it will return this:

```
            "tags": false
```

Basically, I want to make the List of Tags `null` if the deserializer reads its value as `false`.

EDIT: I am using Retrofit and GSON.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320656/8009433

Answer (score 2):

You can create a deserializer like this

```
public class UserResponseDeserializer implements 
JsonDeserializer<ResponseWrapper> {
@Override
public ResponseWrapper deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, 
JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {


    if (((JsonObject) json).get("tags") instanceof JsonArray){
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, ResponseArray.class);
    } else {
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, ResponseBoolean.class);
    }

}
}
```

where `ResponseArray` and `ResponseBoolean` extends `ResponseWrapper` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320656/8009433)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Example implements Serializable
{
@JsonProperty("tags")
private Map<String, Object> tags = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}
```

Use above class for json parsing :

```
Object object = tags.get("tags");

if (object instanceof JSONArray){
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) tags.get("tags");
        }else {
            boolean booleanValue = (boolean) tags.get("tags");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Type adapters, the very heart of Gson serialization/deserialization, can help in almost all cases.
All you need is just implementing one.

```java
final class CollectionFalseAsNullTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory instance = new CollectionFalseAsNullTypeAdapterFactory();

    private CollectionFalseAsNullTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory get() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( !Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            return null;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<Collection<Object>> delegateTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<Collection<Object>>) gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new CollectionFalseAsNullTypeAdapter<>(delegateTypeAdapter);
        return typeAdapter;
    }

    private static final class CollectionFalseAsNullTypeAdapter<E>
            extends TypeAdapter<Collection<E>> {

        private final TypeAdapter<Collection<E>> delegateTypeAdapter;

        private CollectionFalseAsNullTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<Collection<E>> delegateTypeAdapter) {
            this.delegateTypeAdapter = delegateTypeAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Collection<E> value)
                throws IOException {
            delegateTypeAdapter.write(out, value);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<E> read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            // Let's just make sure it's a boolean
            if ( in.peek() == JsonToken.BOOLEAN ) {
                // If yes, then just return a null skipping the boolean
                in.skipValue();
                return null;
            }
            return delegateTypeAdapter.read(in);
        }

    }

}
```

Example of use:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(CollectionFalseAsNullTypeAdapterFactory.get())
        .create();

public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    for ( final String resourceName : ImmutableList.of("non-null.json", "null.json") ) {
        try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = Resources.getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q50013856.class, resourceName) ) {
            final Entity entity = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Entity.class);
            System.out.println(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Example output (assuming `toString` is overridden):

> Entity{tags=[Tag{contentId=13, tagId=3, created=Mon Mar 26 11:09:08 EEST 2018, tagName=FICTION}, Tag{contentId=13, tagId=7, created=Mon Mar 26 11:09:08 EEST 2018, tagName=JUVENILE FICTION}]}
>   Entity{tags=null}

Note that you can annotate your `tags` field to be more accurate rather than registering the factory globally:

```java
@JsonAdapter(CollectionFalseAsNullTypeAdapterFactory.class)
final List<Tag> tags = null;
```

Comment: Hi! I believe this is correct, but I switched to Kotlin now. I used it the same way you did, I declared the JSONAdapter like this: `        @JsonAdapter(CollectionFalseAsNullTypeAdapterFactory::class)` but it still somehow isn't working.