# Retrofit - How can I ignore a field if its data type is different?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, gson

I am using Retrofit 2.4.0, with GsonConverterFactory and RxJavaFactory.

Suppose I am now calling an API named `getSomething`.

In normal situations, server returns

```
{
    status: "ok",
    errorMsg: "",
    data: {...}
}
```

But if an error occurs:

```
{
    status: "error",
    errorMsg: "Some error message",
    data: []
}
```

Note that data becomes an array if an error occurs.

This is how I define the API:

```
@GET("URL")
fun getSomething(): Observable<SomeResponse<SomeObject>>
```

SomeResponse:

```
open class SomeResponse<T> {

    var data: T? = null

    @SerializedName("errorMsg")
    var errorMessage: String? = ""

    var status: String? = ""
}
```

And in an `APIManager` (Singleton):

```
fun getSomething(): Observable<SomeObject> {
    return someAPI.getSomething()
            .map{ response ->
                if (response.status != "ok") throw new APIException(response.errorMessage)
                response.data
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}
```

As you can see, if status is not `"ok"`, an `APIException` which I defined by myself will be thrown with the error message returned from server, so that I can have my own handling (e.g. display a dialog with that error message).

But now it cannot even reach that throw.
Since `data` is now an array, an `JsonSyntaxException` is thrown instead, and therefore I cannot show the correct error message to user.

#### What I want to do

I know that I can delay the parsing of `data` after I check the status, by making all declarations of Retrofit interface to return `Observable<SomeResponse<Any>>`, and do:

```
            .map{ response ->
                if (response.status != "ok") throw new APIException(response.errorMessage)
                response.data
            }
            .map{ data ->
                //Parse the object here
            }
```

Assume I don't want to do that, still relying on GsonConverterFactory to do the parsing, is there a way to throw `APIException` with correct error message?

Comment: if we use Gson then json object or json array both aree considered as JsonElement , so you can recieve data as JsonElement and then use it as json object or json array  coz in oop Parent can hold refrence of child

Comment: You can refer this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245/how-to-handle-dynamic-json-in-retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245/how-to-handle-dynamic-json-in-retrofit)

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you will have to manual parse the response, As Adeel suggested, take 'data' as [JsonElement](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html).

When you get {`status: "error"}` i.e. exception case, you can show the error message, Otherwise in case of {`status: "ok"}`, you can get JsonArray from 'data' and use that array.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative,

If you are using Kotlin, you can bypass this issue declaring the variable as "Any".

```
@SerializedName("my_parameter")
@Expose
var myVar: Any ?= null
```