# JSON data with Object and Array simultaneously

Tags: android, json

How can I parse JSON data like this?

[image]

JSON Link: http://elearnup.com/ajax/classes

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Try not to post  zero effort question . This question asked here a lots of time . So Search first before asking.

Comment: I am new to this . please provide link @ADM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320656/8009433

Comment: Change format of JSON data. It is not in a suitable order. Here chapter should be in Array not in Object. Change JSON format from server.