# Retrofit 2 - parse JSON based on response Type

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2 and i have have api where if user detail available then it will return user detail object or else i will send a message saying user detail not found.

```
 Call<ResponseBody> getCustomerDetail(@Path(value="userDetailId", encoded=true) String userDetailId);
```

if i have above call as `ResponseBody` then if i convert to string then i get string json response.

```
 Log.d("detail",response.body().string());
```

My question is how i can convert response  to My `UserDetail pojo class` ?
if i add  `Call<UserDetail>` then i cant check if user detail not found.so is there any way to achieve this

I have tried below method but not working

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                Log.d("userdetail",obj.toString());
```

another method

```
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
              UserDetail userDetail=gson.fromJson(obj.toString(),UserDetail.class );
```

Three scenarios of response

```
{
"customer_id": 138,
"customer_name": "John",
"customer_address": "Usa",
"customer_primary_mobile": "2353253232325",
"customer_secondary_mobile": "325322353232",
"customer_location": null,
"customer_type_id": 14
}
```

second

```
{
"message": "No Records Found"
}
```

third

```
{
"message": "Some think went wrong"
}
```

Comment: what is your response like, please share the structure(json)

Comment: @NavneetKrishna.updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your response type dont change(always give json object) , add all keys within a json object

```
    public class UserDetail {

@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("customer_id")
@Expose
private Integer customerId;
@SerializedName("customer_name")
@Expose
private String customerName;
@SerializedName("customer_address")
@Expose
private String customerAddress;
@SerializedName("customer_primary_mobile")
@Expose
private String customerPrimaryMobile;
@SerializedName("customer_secondary_mobile")
@Expose
private String customerSecondaryMobile;
@SerializedName("customer_location")
@Expose
private Object customerLocation;
@SerializedName("customer_type_id")
@Expose
private Integer customerTypeId;

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public Integer getCustomerId() {
return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
this.customerId = customerId;
}

public String getCustomerName() {
return customerName;
}

public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
this.customerName = customerName;
}

public String getCustomerAddress() {
return customerAddress;
}

public void setCustomerAddress(String customerAddress) {
this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
}

public String getCustomerPrimaryMobile() {
return customerPrimaryMobile;
}

public void setCustomerPrimaryMobile(String customerPrimaryMobile) {
this.customerPrimaryMobile = customerPrimaryMobile;
}

public String getCustomerSecondaryMobile() {
return customerSecondaryMobile;
}

public void setCustomerSecondaryMobile(String customerSecondaryMobile) {
this.customerSecondaryMobile = customerSecondaryMobile;
}

public Object getCustomerLocation() {
return customerLocation;
}

public void setCustomerLocation(Object customerLocation) {
this.customerLocation = customerLocation;
}

public Integer getCustomerTypeId() {
return customerTypeId;
}

public void setCustomerTypeId(Integer customerTypeId) {
this.customerTypeId = customerTypeId;
}

}
```

then while you get response

```
UserDetail user= gson.fromJson("add json reponse here", UserDetail.class);
```

you can access all fields like `user.getMessage(), user.getCustomerName()`

Comment: @Navneet.thanks got it .what about if entire response is different then how we can handle with different pojo class

Comment: in that case , you will need to try dynamic json parsing like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320656/8009433

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Create a serializer for the request.

```
class UserDetailSerializer{
      @SerializedName("customer_id")
      private Integer customerId;

      ...

      @SerializedName("message")
      private String message;
 }
```

and then you can do some checks and get the UserDetail object or the message. It's important that you use `Integer` and not `int` since it may be null.

It's better in my opinion if you separate `UserDetailSerializer` and `UserDetail` since the extra `message` field can introduce some inconsistency in your code.

I find it useful to use the full potential of Retrofit2 and directly get a POJO and not do the convertion from JSON yourself.

**Old answer**

You can create a POJO as in what you expect the request to contain and then get your UserDetail from it. Since it's a object it can be `null` and you can see if the user exists or not.

Your object

```
class MyResponsePOJO{
    @SerializedName("userdetail")
    UserDetail userDetail;

    ...

    public UserDetail getUserDetail(){
         return this.userDetail;
    }
}
```

and then your Retrofit2 request

```
MyResponsePOJO getCustomerDetail(@Path(value="userDetailId", encoded=true) String userDetailId);
```

and simply get it by calling the getter

```
UserDetail userDetail = myResponsePOJO.getUserDetail();
```

*If you provide the JSON you are getting I can give you a more precises answer.*

Comment: @vicktor thanks. what about if entire response is different then  how we can handle with different pojo class

Comment: @vision I don't think this is desirable. You are calling the UserDetails API Endpoint and are expecting a certain type of data. IMHO you should use the `UserDetails` class and check HTTP response codes for more info instead of using the `message` field. Your solution brings a lot of uncertainty and is hard to test your code later.

Comment: @Victor.yes ur right.i am just learning android so.thanks for he tips

Answer (score 0):

you can use direct json response to get pojo reference

```
UserDetail userDetail = new Gson().fromJson(response.body().string(), UserDetail.class);
```

Comment: @if i try to log Log.d("userDetail",userDetail.toString()); then it will throw an exception null pointer exception