# How to create a JSON Converter for objects that can be either a String or a Custom Object

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

Our back-end implements a Login API with responses like this:

Successful Response:

```
{
    "response": "SUCCESS",
    "details": {
        "user_id": "912341",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
        "address": "John Doe's House",
        "birthdate": "2018-07-09",
        "profile_file_id": null
    }
}
```

Error reponse:

```
{
    "response": "FAILED",
    "details": "Invalid email"
}
```

How can I make my GSON and Retrofit Serializer dynamic to allow data changes like this? I am using Retrofit 2, Gson, and RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.

Comment: may be its not possible with help of GSON, either you have to add different key string like "error":"error message" and check if it is null or empty?

Comment: you want to both data fetching.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle Dynamic JSON in Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245/how-to-handle-dynamic-json-in-retrofit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ResponseData {

    @SerializedName("response")
    private String response;

    @SerializedName("details")
    private String details;

    public String getError(){
        if(response.equals("FAILED")
            return details;
        else return null; 
    }

    public UserData getUserData(){
        if(response.equals("SUCCESS")
           return new Gson().fromJson(details, UserData.class);
        else return null;
    }
```

and Retrofit2 with RxJava2

```
MaybeObserver<ResponseData> getUserData(...)
```

However in my opinion your API design introduces some failure potential. Use HTTP response codes instead.

Comment: This is true. I'll suggest to change it to a more semantic way next time. However, I changed your `String details` to a `JsonElement`. But this worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

make pojo class like this way..

```
public class Details{

@SerializedName("address")
private String address;

@SerializedName("birthdate")
private String birthdate;

@SerializedName("profile_file_id")
private Object profileFileId;

@SerializedName("user_id")
private String userId;

@SerializedName("name")
private String name;

@SerializedName("email")
private String email;

public void setAddress(String address){
    this.address = address;
}

public String getAddress(){
    return address;
}

public void setBirthdate(String birthdate){
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
}

public String getBirthdate(){
    return birthdate;
}

public void setProfileFileId(Object profileFileId){
    this.profileFileId = profileFileId;
}

public Object getProfileFileId(){
    return profileFileId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId){
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserId(){
    return userId;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}

}
```

ResponseData..

```
public class ResponseData extends ErrorResponse{

@SerializedName("response")
private String response;

@SerializedName("details")
private String details;

public void setResponse(String response){
    this.response = response;
}

public String getResponse(){
    return response;
}

public void setDetails(String details){
    this.details = details;
}

public String getDetails(){
    return details;
}

}
```

Error Response..

```
public class ErrorResponse {

@SerializedName("response")
private String response;

@SerializedName("details")
private String details;
```

}

make api call into interface..

```
@GET("path")
Call<ResponseData> getUserData();
```

api called.

```
        Call<ResponseData> dataCall=apiInterface.getUserData();
    dataCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseData> call, Response<ResponseData> response) {
            if (response!=null && response.isSuccessful() && response.body()!=null){

            }
            else{
                if (response.errorBody()!=null){
                    ErrorResponse errorResponse=new Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody().toString(),ErrorResponse.class);
                    Log.d("Error data",response.errorBody().toString());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseData> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not correct to use the same property to contain 2 semantically different types of information. You are sort of applying polymorphism on a class internally (using the state of some inner porperty to decide the content *type* of some other porperty). What I would do is add another property parallel do `details`, like `errorDetails` which will be populated with the error reason in the case where an error occurs. In this case you have 2 separate fields to handle the data according to the type of response.