# Retrofit2 - GSON - Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING or Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I am getting the following exception on my Retrofit2 call:

**com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 22311 path $[1].programme[3].credits.presenter**

I probably know why it is being thrown. Some "credits" objects have more than one "presenters", and they are given as JSON Arrays (**{"presenter":["Barbara Schledduytkew","Hubert Muckhutgoldwes"]}**), however, some others have only a single "presenter", and it is given as a JSON Object (**{"presenter":"Rosalynda Demstogtrojkt"}**)

I need to find a way to get the presenter items parsed in both cases. I guess that I have to write my own custom TypeAdapter, but I am not sure and need help. Thanks in advance.

**Retrofit Instance:**

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.URL_HOST)
                .client(okHttpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

**Credits Class**:

```
public class Credits {

    @SerializedName("director")
    @Expose
    private List<String> director;
    @SerializedName("actor")
    @Expose
    private List<String> actor = null;
    @SerializedName("presenter")
    @Expose
    private List<String> presenter;
    @SerializedName("commentator")
    @Expose
    private String commentator;

    public List<String> getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(List<String> director) {
        this.director = director;
    }

    public List<String> getActor() {
        return actor;
    }

    public void setActor(List<String> actor) {
        this.actor = actor;
    }

    public List<String> getPresenter() {
        return presenter;
    }

    public void setPresenter(List<String> presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    public String getCommentator() {
        return commentator;
    }

    public void setCommentator(String commentator) {
        this.commentator = commentator;
    }
}
```

Comment: use deserialiser, see this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/46320656/8009433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right on why this error happens. It tries to parse an Array but receives a String. As for your data, it is better to stick with the same model. Which means: Making the backend also returning an array even when it contains only one presenter.

Nevertheless, yes: we can fix this with a custom Type Adapter.
This custom type adapter will simply check in the read-part whether it gets a String or an Array. And if it gets a String, we rewrite it to the List variant.

**The type adapter**

A type adapter does two things:

- Defines what should be done when reading the json -> `read()` method.
- Defines what should be done when writing the json -> `write()` method.

The latter one is not used in this case, as we only try to read the data. So we just write the array for the `write()` method. Kinda similar to the original type adapter implementation of Collections.

**Reading the data**

- We first check whether we receive a String in json by using `reader.peek() == JsonToken.STRING` in the `read()` method. If so, we create the list ourselves.
- If we get an array, we parse it as it used to be.

**Result**
The resulting type adapter will look like this:

```
public class ListFromStringTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<List<String>> {

    public List<String> read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
        if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            reader.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
        if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.STRING) {
            // ** This is the part where we fix the issue **
            // If we receive a String, get this and put it in a list.
            // Result will be that item in a list.
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(reader.nextString());
            return list;
        } else {
            // Else we expect to receive the array.
            // Based on original collection implementation:
            // https://github.com/google/gson/blob/0636635cbffa08157bdbd558b1212e4d806474eb/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            reader.beginArray();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                String value = reader.nextString();
                list.add(value);
            }
            reader.endArray();
            return list;
        }
    }

    public void write(JsonWriter writer, List<String> list) throws IOException {
        // Simply writing the array, we don't need to modify anything here.
        // Based on original collection type adapter implementation:
        // https://github.com/google/gson/blob/0636635cbffa08157bdbd558b1212e4d806474eb/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java
        if (list == null) {
            writer.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        writer.beginArray();
        for (String string : list) {
            writer.value(string);
        }
        writer.endArray();
    }
}
```

**Registering the type adapter**
As last, we need to tell Gson to use this type adapter for the List class, so modify where you create the Gson object:

```
// Get the type token for gson
Type collectionStringType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
// Create gson object
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(collectionStringType, new ListFromStringTypeAdapter())
        .create();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this through a custom JsonDeserializer that checks whether the `presenter` key is a String or an Array:

```
public final class CreditsJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Credits> {

    private CreditsJsonDeserializer() {}

    private static final CreditsJsonDeserializer INSTANCE = new CreditsJsonDeserializer();

    public static CreditsJsonDeserializer instance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public Credits deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json.isJsonObject()) {
            // Set up an object to return
            Credits newCredits = new Credits();
            // Loop through the keys in our JSON object
            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> kvp : json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
                // Get key
                String key = kvp.getKey();
                // Get value
                JsonElement value = kvp.getValue();
                // If we have a null value, just go to the next key
                if (value.isJsonNull()) continue;
                // Check our key to see which field we need to deserialize
                switch (key) {
                    // Deserialize our List of Directors
                    case "director":
                        newCredits.setDirector(context.deserialize(value, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType()));
                        break;
                    // Deserialize our List of Actors
                    case "actor":
                        newCredits.setActor(context.deserialize(value, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType()));
                        break;
                    // Deserialize our Presenter name or List of Presenters
                    case "presenter":
                        // Check if it's a singular name
                        if (value.isJsonPrimitive() && value.getAsJsonPrimitive().isString()) {
                            ArrayList<String> presenters = new ArrayList<>();
                            presenters.add(value.getAsString());
                            newCredits.setPresenter(presenters);
                        }
                        // Else, it's an Array of names
                        else {
                          newCredits.setPresenter(context.deserialize(value, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType()));
                        }
                        break;
                    // Deserialize our Commentator name
                    case "commentator":
                        newCredits.setCommentator(value.getAsString());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return newCredits;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, change your Retrofit instance code to use the new Deserializer:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Credits.class, CreditsJsonDeserializer.instance())
                .create();

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.URL_HOST)
                .client(okHttpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```