# JsonArray as empty string parsing issue with retrofit

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I have a json in which 1 key is coming as jsonArray if it has data otherwise it is coming as empty string. It is giving error while parsing in gson with retrofit.

```
  "section": "Technology",
  "subsection": "",
  "title": "Depiction of Amazon Stirs a Debate About Work Culture",
  "abstract": "Details of working conditions at Amazon led to a response from employees, relatives and friends.",
  "url": "http://www.nytimes.com/2015/08/19/technology/amazon-workplace-reactions-comments.html",
  "byline": "By THE NEW YORK TIMES",
  "item_type": "Article",
  "updated_date": "2015-08-18T07:35:33-5:00",
  "created_date": "2015-08-18T07:35:35-5:00",
  "published_date": "2015-08-19T04:00:00-5:00",
  "material_type_facet": "News",
  "kicker": "",
  "des_facet": [
    "Workplace Environment"
  ],
  "org_facet": [
    "Amazon.com Inc"
  ],
  "per_facet": "",
  "geo_facet": "",
```

des_facet , org_facet, per_facet, geo_facet are jsonArray but you can see that 2 are not having data so coming as empty string.

How to handle this scenario with retrofit +gson.

Json format can't be changed here at server.

is there any way I can achieve it in android?

Comment: You want to handle while setting data while it's null or empty?

Comment: @AkshayKatariya : I am getting this response from server and I need to parse it in android using retrofit and gson.

Comment: You are using custom parsing or `GsonConverterFactory` ?

Comment: as you are using Retrofit you response should have one format. It should always be an array.

Comment: @AkshayKatariya : Yes I am using GsonConverterFactory

Comment: @AkshayKatariya: is there any way I can ignore these field? gson don't parse them.

Comment: Yes just remove them from your model and it will ignore them while parsing response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there are two option you can solve this

### Option 1:

`JSON` which I used as a example

```
"des_facet": [
        "Workplace Environment"
    ],
    "org_facet": [
        "Amazon.com Inc"
    ],
    "per_facet": ["Akshay"],
    "geo_facet": ""
```

In your model class convert those variable to `Object` type

```
@Expose
    @SerializedName("geo_facet")
    private Object geo_facet;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("per_facet")
    private Object per_facet;
```

then where you want to set data do the following

```
if (model != null)
        {
            if (model.getGeo_facet() != null || model.getGeo_facet() != "")
            {
                Object arr = model.getGeo_facet();
            }
            if (model.getPer_facet() !=null || model.getPer_facet()!= "")
            {
                Object arr = model.getPer_facet();
                if (arr!=null && arr.toString().length()>0)
                {
                    arr = arr.toString();
                    Log.d("akshay","arr= "+arr);
                    //Do your Stuff or Set data
                }
            }
        }
```

> This is the output= 08-11 16:51:29.830 17951-17951/com.android.example
>   D/akshay: arr= [Akshay]

### Option 2:

[Follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28576252/4762767) which is a little bit complex

### Option 3:

Write own custom Parsing [like this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) and Handle your response accordingly

Answer (score 0):

a json can have a single structure. From the code it is clear that the key is given with 2 types of data

Ideally, it should not give `""` when no items. It should give **`null`**

Please change the data

If no items,

```
"des_facet"=null // this is the change on server side. No need to change it on app side
```

If it has items

```
"des_facet"=[
    "Workplace Environment"
  ]
```

**instead of**

If no items,

```
"des_facet"=""
```

If it has items

```
"des_facet"=[
    "Workplace Environment"
  ]
```

Comment: It was never mentioned "server change is not possible". And this is the standars way of API/JSON creation. this scenario can't be fixed from app side even in a hacky way. Because even the Object class can't be mapped with array or List as they are interfaces. So I don't see any way handling this on app side.

Comment: There is always a way my dear have a look at my answer, I handled it at app side

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AutoValue` with `gson` plugin and mark the field as nullable which will notify the Autovalue to make this field optional.
AZs an example this is how you do it:

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class NewsResponse{

       public static TypeAdapter<NewsResponse> typeAdapter(Gson  gson){
               return new AutoValue_NewsResponse.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
       }

       @SerializedName("api_status")
       public abstract String apiStatus();

       @SerializedName("api_text")
       public abstract String success();

       @Nullable
       @SerializedName("errors")
       public abstract ErrorDetails errorDetails();

        @SerializedName("news")
        public abstract List<NewsDetails> newsDetails();
}
```

you must import both of them see more info about importing at: [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) and [AutoValue Gson Plugin](https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson)