# Retrofit gson with dynamic keys

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I've managed to get it to work without a dynamic key. By following this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-retrofit-2--cms-27792) with this [json](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow):

Currently, I'm using Retrofit and trying to get a response with dynamic keys. However, the response body is always null:

[image]

This is the response format:

```
{
    "dynamic1": {
        "cityID": "id1",
        "priceRange": 15
    },
    "dynamic2": {
        "cityID": "id2",
        "priceRange": 15
    }
}
```

In APIUtils.java

```
    public static CityService getCitiesService() {
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(CityService.class);
    }
```

In CityService.java

```
public interface CityService {

    @GET("/SAGetStrollAwayCity")
    Call<CityResponse> getCities();

    @GET("/SAGetStrollAwayCity")
    Call<CityResponse> getCities(@Query("tagged") String tags);
}
```

In CityResponse.java:

```
public class CityResponse {
    /*@SerializedName("results")
    @Expose*/ // is this the correct way?
    private Map<String, CityDetails> city = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, CityDetails> getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(Map<String, CityDetails> elemDetails) {
        this.city = elemDetails;
    }

}
```

In CityDetails.java

```
public class CityDetails {

    @SerializedName("cityID")
    @Expose
    private String cityID;
    @SerializedName("priceRange")
    @Expose
    private Integer priceRange;

    public String getCityID() {
        return cityID;
    }

    public void setCityID(String cityID) {
        this.cityID = cityID;
    }

    public Integer getPriceRange() {
        return priceRange;
    }

    public void setPriceRange(Integer priceRange) {
        this.priceRange = priceRange;
    }

}
```

In HomeFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
        // 2nd api call
        mServiceCity = ApiUtils.getCitiesService();
        loadCities();

        return rootView;
}

public void loadCities() {
    mServiceCity.getCities().enqueue(new Callback<CityResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CityResponse> call, Response<CityResponse> response) {
         // !!! WHY IS THE RESPONSE BODY EMPTY???
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {

//                    adapter.updateCities(response.body().getCity());

                Log.d("MainActivity", "posts loaded from API"+ response.body().getCity());
            }else {
                int statusCode  = response.code();
                // handle request errors depending on status code
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CityResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            //showErrorMessage();
            Log.d("MainActivity", "error loading from API");

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the response you are expecting?

Comment: Hi this is the response: {
    "dynamic1": {
        "cityID": "id1",
        "priceRange": 15
    },
    "dynamic2": {
        "cityID": "id2",
        "priceRange": 15
    }
}

Comment: Okay, you mean to say this is not coming, it's always coming empty right?

Comment: Your CityResponse model is wrong as there is no @SerializedName(), how will it know from which key it needs to parse..!!

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån updated the questions with breakpoint at the response

Comment: @PrashanthVerma, I see... However, the keys are dynamic for keys "dynamic1" and "dynamic2". How can I go about it? In iOS it's much easier using NSDictionary with keys and values

Comment: May i know why do you want dynamic keys?

Comment: In this line: `private Map<String, CityDetails> city = new HashMap<>();` change `city` to `cityID` and try.

Comment: refer option 3 from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51799218/4762767

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758601/parse-dynamic-key-json-string-using-retrofit, I am not sure this is the right answer but go through it.

Comment: @PrashanthVerma that's how the response is... and I'm just consuming it...

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån it just change the variable name... don't think changing city to cityID will do anything

Comment: hmm..there are only fixed set of keys will come? or like any key can come, i mean are the keys not predictable..?

Comment: It's not predictable it's dynamic

Comment: @PrabhaKaran, that's what I'm referring to... I'm changing "public class ResultInside" in the answer to "public class CityResponse". What's wrong here?

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån, I've tried your suggestion to change it... However, just by looking at it, my gut feeling is telling me that. And apparently that's the result when I debug it after changing. Please do not feel offended. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I deleted the comment. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I'd drop the `CityResponse` model and just work with `Map<String, CityDetails>`.

The retrofit interface can then be:

```
public interface CityService {

  @GET("/SAGetStrollAwayCity")
  Call<Map<String, CityDetails>> getCities();

  @GET("/SAGetStrollAwayCity")
  Call<Map<String, CityDetails>> getCities(@Query("tagged") String tags);
}
```

In your scenario, the response body is empty because `CityResponse` would map to a json like:

```
{
  "city": {
    "dynamic1": {
      "cityID": "id1",
      "priceRange": 15
    },
    "dynamic2": {
      "cityID": "id2",
      "priceRange": 15
    }
  }
}
```

However, you don't have a root element called `city`. The json itself can already be mapped to a java `Map`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: :D That's fine, no worries! Glad it helped! Buy the beer to someone else in more need than me :D

Comment: Thank's a lot...didn't knew we can actually parse json with map