# Easy way to parse Key value pair json

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit, pojo

I want to parse the json . I know retrofit and working on it, but don't know how to parse the below json as it is not in correct format.

Kindly help me in solving this. Number of Universities in the json is not static they will change .

```
{
    "transactionid": "7ec7d209589ce2abdb2e555c26776c85",
    "returncode": "200",
    "returnmsg": "success",
    "university": {
        "1": "Anna University",
        "3": "Technological University",
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you do so far ?

Comment: I want to parse this json. I dont know how to create pojo for this json as it is having a structure of key values.

Comment: paste your json here and get POJO zip file. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: are you the one writing the api ? you need to change the 'university' field to an array else it's a pain to get the data

Comment: nope i asked my team to change the json as follows                                                     "university": {
        "id":"1,                                                                                               
         "name": Anna University"
    }   but they told they cant change as we are using same api for all platforms.

Comment: change it to array will be easier to parse

Comment: @OussemaAroua  yes bro I know that will work like a charm ,but cant change the json now. :-(

Comment: i tried that already it wont give proper pojo class for this json.

Comment: Retrofit has nothing to do with parsing, it is made for network requests, not parsing.

Comment: Please check this link
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245`

Comment: create a university class with two hashmap fields instead of changing university to an array

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Ok bro. know that used wrong word.

Comment: @RujulGandhi thanks bro .will see the link.

Comment: why not use gson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JsonDeserializer`, import in you gradle file

> com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0

and use class below

```
 public static class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<YourResponseModel> {

    @Override
    public YourResponseModel deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        YourResponseModel response = new YourResponseModel();
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject university = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("university");
        ArrayList<String> universities = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(university.toString());
            Iterator<String> iter = object.keys();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                String key = iter.next();
                try {
                    String value = object.getString(key);
                    universities.add(value);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "deserialize: ",e );
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        response.university = universities;
        return response;
    }
}
```

Create new GsonBuilder for the JsonDeserializer

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(YourResponseModel.class, new MyDeserializer())
                .create();
```

and finally set it to the Retrofit Builder

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
```

You can get more information from this [blog](https://medium.com/@andersonk/retrofit-2-custom-deserializer-for-unwrapping-properties-8cb8b2ec901e)