# Parse key value pair using retrofit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "response_code": 200,
    "message": "data list",
    "data": [
        {
            "Assigned": "14",
            "Closed": "150",
            "Escalated TTO": "102",
            "Escalated TTR": "2",
            "New": "44",
            "Pending": "4",
            "Resolved": "14"
        }
    ]
}
```

Above is the response that I want to parse, but I don't want to create a static POJO for it. The model should be dynamic so that even if there is another key-value pair in the above response, like as shown below, the response is able to be parsed I guess it is possible using `HashMap`.

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "response_code": 200,
    "message": "data list",
    "data": [
        {
            "Assigned": "14",
            "Closed": "150",
            "Escalated TTO": "102",
            "Escalated TTR": "2",
            "New": "44",
            "Pending": "4",
            "Resolved": "14",
            "xx": "xx",
            "xx": "xx",
            "xx": "xx",


        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245/how-to-handle-dynamic-json-in-retrofit

Comment: You mean just returning `Map<String, JsonElement>`?

Comment: @Fred Since both key and value are string so probably "Map<String, String>"

Comment: That's why I was asking. Is it just for `data`? If it's the whole response, then `data` is not a `String`, but an object

Comment: Sorry for the confusion this is just for the data..I just want to know how to structure my model so that I can succesfully parse it

Comment: then you are only left with using HashMap<String, Object>

Comment: @vikaskumar why not HashMap<String, String> since both key and value are string

Comment: as long as you can guarantee that there won't be any objects coming in json you are good to use String but if you are not sure then it's better to go with object.

Comment: @vikaskumar, yes thats guaranteed, can you give a proper answer on how should be the structure of my model class so that Im successfully able to parse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the ideal scenario would be a `Map<String, String>`. The models could look like (assuming you're using Gson. Should be similar for others):

```
data class ApiResponse(
  @SerializedName("result")
  val result: String,
  @SerializedName("responseCode")
  val responseCode: Int,
  @SerializedName("message")
  val message: String,
  @SerializedName("data")
  val data: List<Map<String, String>>
)
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks a ton :)