# Is it possible to use a single class to parse a json response with Retrofit ? If so, how should I start to structure it?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

**1st**

```
{
  "data": {
    "weather": [
      {
        "location": "location1",
        "condition": "condition1",
      },
      {
        "location": "location2",
        "condition": "condition2",
      }
    ],
    "total": 2
  },
  "sucess": true
}
```

**2nd**

```
{
  "data": {
    "syncRequired": true,
    "totalOfLocations": 0
  },
  "success": true
}
```

These 2 blocks are generally the response that I get from my API calls, and how I have been parsing it is by creating 2 different POJO classes for each response. Generally this is how it should look like for the **2nd** block of json response.

```
public class JsonResponse {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;
   
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private DataSync data;

    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public DataSync getDataSync() {
        return data;
    }
    
    public void setDataSync() {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

and then parse inside the **data** key likewise

```
public class DataSync{

    @SerializedName("syncRequired")
    @Expose
    private Boolean syncRequired;

    @SerializedName("totalOfLocations")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalOfLocations;

    public Boolean isSyncRequired() {
        return syncRequired;
    }

    public void setSyncRequired(Boolean success) {
        this.syncRequired= syncRequired;
    }

    public Integer getTotalOfLocations() {
        return totalOfLocations;
    }

    public void setTotalOfLocations() {
        this.totalOfLocations= totalOfLocations;
    }
}
```

My aim is to use a single class of JsonResponse to parse every response that I get, and map the **Data** to their relevant Data classes for further parsing. Let me know if you need more information so that its easier to help me with my questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not use a Single class for parsing you have to create pojo classes for each different response . What you can do is define a base Contract for response and Use it for all the responses . Something [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63859992/4168607).

Comment: @ADM *You can not use a Single class for parsing* **this is not true** ... he can obviously create object with sum of all properties (of course they have to be optional/nullable) ... does it make sens - it depends , is it doable - **yes, it is**

Comment: @Selvin you r right . there is no bound on number of fields in a class . So why not create one with 1000 fields .

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the question is wrong ... The question prolly is (which obviously is asked here again and again): How to parse json if response can be one of x ... of course answer can be found with internet search

Comment: also ... he can make `data`  `JSONObject`

Comment: You guys have a good point. Thanks for the reference @ADM.

Comment: Thanks for the good insight @Selvin  I have been looking up multiple references in the net and have understood that there are some cases where I could use a single POJO for multiple api parsing. But I am looking for the solution to a case where 'data' will return either Object or Array. At this point I guess the ones that does not need tedious work is to have a separate pojo classes for each of them. Will still be on the lookout though.