# How can I define dynamic data class? (Android - Retrofit2)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, httprequest

I am developing an Android App via Kotlin. The app uses Retrofit2 for HTTP requests. I used Retrofit2 over and over but I don't know how to solve this scenario.

I want to use an API which needs a query like query1, query2 etc. (Close to 100 values available)

For Example:

```
When I send a request via "query1" the response object has coordinates: List<List<List<Double>>>
When I send a request via "query2" the response object has coordinates: List<List<Double>>
When I send a request via "query3" the response object has coordinates: List<List<List<List<Double>>>>
When I send a request via "query4" the response object has coordinates: List<List<Double>>
```

I don't know how API returns the inner list count.
By the way there is just one coordinates in the object.

The response object in JSON format

```
[
    {
        "key-1": "value-1",
        "key-2": "value-2",
        "key-3": "value-3",
        "key-4": {
            "inner-key": [
                [
                    [
                        1.0,
                        1.0
                    ],
                    [
                        1.0,
                        1.0
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "key-1": "value-1",
        "key-2": "value-2",
        "key-3": "value-3",
        "key-4": {
            "inner-key": [
                [
                    [
                        [
                            1.0,
                            1.0
                        ],
                        [
                            1.0,
                            1.0
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            1.0,
                            1.0
                        ],
                        [
                            1.0,
                            1.0
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Here is my data classes. But I don't know how can I define the "key4" object.

```
data class Response(
    val key1: String? = null,
    val key2: String? = null,
    val key3: String? = null,
    val key4: key4? = null,
)
data class key4(
    //How should I define the "inner-key" object
)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Your problem isn't with Retrofit, its with whatever you're using to convert JSON to objects.  Most likely GSON or Jackson.  But we'd need to know which one you were using to even attempt to help.  But both of those libraries have their own way of overriding the behavior of the converter for a type, which you'd likely have to do.

Also, since these 4 objects come from 4 different queries, the trivial thing thing would be to parse each query into a different object, rather than using one for all 4 queries.  You could also just make it a list and worry about which it is when using the data.

Comment: Check [https://stackoverflow.com/a/34957125/3022836](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34957125/3022836)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

I tried a few way for solution. I didn't know it's perfect solution but there is my **solution**:

There is my data class which name is key4 on my question.

```
data class key4(
    val inner-key: List<Any>? = null
)
```

Also I cast inner-key like:

```
val temp = response?.key4?.inner-key as List<List<Double>>?
```

or

```
val temp = response?.key4?.inner-key as List<List<List<Double>>>?
```