# Handling Retrofit Response by type

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm Using Tmap Route Api

In retrofit's response there are two types in Geometry.type

Point and LineString

but Point type returns List<String> data of coordinates,
and LinsString type returns List<List<String>>

I don't know how to handle this data
[ERROR IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Wku.jpg)

[image: Retrofit Interface]

[image: DataClass]

Response data is like this

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.92364851900282,
          37.556774278906374
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "totalDistance": 1015,
        "totalTime": 802,
        "index": 0,
        "pointIndex": 0,
        "name": "",
        "description": "31m 이동",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "",
        "facilityType": "14",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 200,
        "pointType": "SP"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.92364851900282,
            37.556774278906374
          ],
          [
            126.92370962321058,
            37.556821496731125
          ],
          [
            126.92390126832917,
            37.55696592780928
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 1,
        "lineIndex": 0,
        "name": "",
        "description": ", 31m",
        "distance": 31,
        "time": 30,
        "roadType": 24,
        "categoryRoadType": 0,
        "facilityType": "14",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.92390126832917,
          37.55696592780928
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 2,
        "pointIndex": 1,
        "name": "홍대입구역  8번출구",
        "description": "홍대입구역  8번출구 에서 우회전 후 33m 이동 ",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "홍대입구역  8번출구",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "",
        "facilityType": "14",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 13,
        "pointType": "GP"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.92390126832917,
            37.55696592780928
          ],
          [
            126.92405403539615,
            37.556852054896595
          ],
          [
            126.92414569166857,
            37.55692427036115
          ],
          [
            126.92418457724796,
            37.556915938692605
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 3,
        "lineIndex": 1,
        "name": "",
        "description": ", 33m",
        "distance": 33,
        "time": 34,
        "roadType": 24,
        "categoryRoadType": 0,
        "facilityType": "14",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.92418457724796,
          37.556915938692605
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 4,
        "pointIndex": 2,
        "name": "",
        "description": "직진 후 보행자도로 을 따라 14m 이동 ",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "홍대입구역8번출구",
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 11,
        "pointType": "GP"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.92418457724796,
            37.556915938692605
          ],
          [
            126.92432900946721,
            37.556882611819624
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 5,
        "lineIndex": 2,
        "name": "보행자도로",
        "description": "보행자도로, 14m",
        "distance": 14,
        "time": 10,
        "roadType": 24,
        "categoryRoadType": 1,
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.92432900946721,
            37.556882611819624
          ],
          [
            126.92462898949327,
            37.556621536437405
          ],
          [
            126.92502340786467,
            37.55627158419173
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 6,
        "lineIndex": 3,
        "name": "",
        "description": ", 91m",
        "distance": 91,
        "time": 70,
        "roadType": 22,
        "categoryRoadType": 1,
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.92502340786467,
          37.55627158419173
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 7,
        "pointIndex": 3,
        "name": "훼미리마트 홍대공원점",
        "description": "훼미리마트 홍대공원점 에서 우회전 후 6m 이동 ",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "훼미리마트 홍대공원점",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "",
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 13,
        "pointType": "GP"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.92502340786467,
            37.55627158419173
          ],
          [
            126.92499563293248,
            37.556260473875554
          ],
          [
            126.92497063568169,
            37.556243808699506
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 8,
        "lineIndex": 4,
        "name": "",
        "description": ", 6m",
        "distance": 6,
        "time": 5,
        "roadType": 0,
        "categoryRoadType": 0,
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.92497063568169,
          37.556243808699506
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 9,
        "pointIndex": 4,
        "name": "훼미리마트 홍대공원점",
        "description": "훼미리마트 홍대공원점 에서 좌회전 후 14m 이동 ",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "훼미리마트 홍대공원점",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "",
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 12,
        "pointType": "GP"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.92497063568169,
            37.556243808699506
          ],
          [
            126.92496508141669,
            37.556216034052206
          ],
          [
            126.92496508227926,
            37.55618548204952
          ],
          [
            126.9249900809415,
            37.55615215303936
          ],
          [
            126.92502063418243,
            37.55613548885734
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 10,
        "lineIndex": 5,
        "name": "",
        "description": ", 14m",
        "distance": 14,
        "time": 10,
        "roadType": 0,
        "categoryRoadType": 0,
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.92502063418243,
          37.55613548885734
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 11,
        "pointIndex": 5,
        "name": "형님저여요",
        "description": "형님저여요 에서 우회전 후 어울마당로 을 따라 99m 이동 ",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "형님저여요",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "",
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 13,
        "pointType": "GP"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.92502063418243,
            37.55613548885734
          ],
          [
            126.92499841625978,
            37.55605494227082
          ],
          [
            126.92504841280014,
            37.55601605879839
          ],
          [
            126.9253206145225,
            37.5558633036557
          ],
          [
            126.92582335439296,
            37.55558278971788
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 12,
        "lineIndex": 6,
        "name": "어울마당로",
        "description": "어울마당로, 99m",
        "distance": 99,
        "time": 77,
        "roadType": 0,
        "categoryRoadType": 0,
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.92582335439296,
          37.55558278971788
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 13,
        "pointIndex": 6,
        "name": "꿈꾸는다락방",
        "description": "꿈꾸는다락방 에서 우회전 후 57m 이동 ",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "꿈꾸는다락방",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "",
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 13,
        "pointType": "GP"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.92582335439296,
            37.55558278971788
          ],
          [
            126.92546228819367,
            37.55515783267321
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 14,
        "lineIndex": 7,
        "name": "",
        "description": ", 57m",
        "distance": 57,
        "time": 43,
        "roadType": 0,
        "categoryRoadType": 0,
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.92546228819367,
          37.55515783267321
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 15,
        "pointIndex": 7,
        "name": "원스샵",
        "description": "원스샵 에서 좌회전 후 242m 이동 ",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "원스샵",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "",
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 12,
        "pointType": "GP"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.92546228819367,
            37.55515783267321
          ],
          [
            126.92598447105019,
            37.55486620926375
          ],
          [
            126.92651498632408,
            37.55458014091298
          ],
          [
            126.92704550152,
            37.55429685001698
          ],
          [
            126.92757046205924,
            37.55399967174757
          ],
          [
            126.9277148956124,
            37.55391912814301
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 16,
        "lineIndex": 8,
        "name": "",
        "description": ", 242m",
        "distance": 242,
        "time": 187,
        "roadType": 0,
        "categoryRoadType": 0,
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.9277148956124,
          37.55391912814301
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 17,
        "pointIndex": 8,
        "name": "",
        "description": "경유지 후 45m 이동 ",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "",
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 0,
        "pointType": "PP1"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.9277148956124,
            37.55391912814301
          ],
          [
            126.92813986354142,
            37.5536830520898
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 18,
        "lineIndex": 9,
        "name": "",
        "description": ", 45m",
        "distance": 45,
        "time": 35,
        "roadType": 22,
        "categoryRoadType": 1,
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.92813986354142,
          37.5536830520898
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 19,
        "pointIndex": 9,
        "name": "디자인창조의아침",
        "description": "디자인창조의아침 에서 4시 방향 우회전 후 216m 이동 ",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "디자인창조의아침",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "",
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 19,
        "pointType": "GP"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.92813986354142,
            37.5536830520898
          ],
          [
            126.92703719348953,
            37.55342750651533
          ],
          [
            126.92684276817901,
            37.553377508849685
          ],
          [
            126.92664834279007,
            37.55333028863888
          ],
          [
            126.9264955793292,
            37.55331639863127
          ],
          [
            126.92630948518114,
            37.55331639530126
          ],
          [
            126.9260261768881,
            37.55334416477975
          ],
          [
            126.92598173641613,
            37.553346941439344
          ],
          [
            126.92593729578735,
            37.553355273008535
          ],
          [
            126.92589841028618,
            37.55336082722232
          ],
          [
            126.9257734215225,
            37.5533663798954
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 20,
        "lineIndex": 10,
        "name": "",
        "description": ", 216m",
        "distance": 216,
        "time": 154,
        "roadType": 22,
        "categoryRoadType": 1,
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.9257734215225,
          37.5533663798954
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 21,
        "pointIndex": 10,
        "name": "",
        "description": "경유지 후 와우산로 을 따라 132m 이동 ",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "",
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 0,
        "pointType": "PP2"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.9257734215225,
            37.5533663798954
          ],
          [
            126.92547067094945,
            37.55338026175211
          ],
          [
            126.92525680273162,
            37.55333859610324
          ],
          [
            126.92502904830212,
            37.55324693601951
          ],
          [
            126.92498460814379,
            37.553238602859935
          ],
          [
            126.92493739069609,
            37.55322193728625
          ],
          [
            126.92486239831604,
            37.5531941613964
          ],
          [
            126.92476518589602,
            37.55316083019936
          ],
          [
            126.92472074612971,
            37.55313860976579
          ],
          [
            126.92468463870198,
            37.55312472184571
          ],
          [
            126.92438466941691,
            37.55300528592197
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 22,
        "lineIndex": 11,
        "name": "와우산로",
        "description": "와우산로, 132m",
        "distance": 132,
        "time": 123,
        "roadType": 21,
        "categoryRoadType": 1,
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.92438466941691,
          37.55300528592197
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 23,
        "pointIndex": 11,
        "name": "호아빈 홍대점",
        "description": "호아빈 홍대점 에서 좌측 횡단보도 후 보행자도로 을 따라 20m 이동 ",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "호아빈 홍대점",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "홍익대앞",
        "facilityType": "15",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 212,
        "pointType": "GP"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.92438466941691,
            37.55300528592197
          ],
          [
            126.92448466484962,
            37.5528441953326
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 24,
        "lineIndex": 12,
        "name": "보행자도로",
        "description": "보행자도로, 20m",
        "distance": 20,
        "time": 13,
        "roadType": 21,
        "categoryRoadType": 1,
        "facilityType": "15",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.92448466484962,
          37.5528441953326
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 25,
        "pointIndex": 12,
        "name": "세븐일레븐 홍대정문점",
        "description": "세븐일레븐 홍대정문점 에서 우회전 후 와우산로 을 따라 15m 이동 ",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "세븐일레븐 홍대정문점",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "홍익대앞",
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 13,
        "pointType": "GP"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            126.92448466484962,
            37.5528441953326
          ],
          [
            126.92437356512016,
            37.552799754067905
          ],
          [
            126.92432912519702,
            37.55278308854395
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 26,
        "lineIndex": 13,
        "name": "와우산로",
        "description": "와우산로, 15m",
        "distance": 15,
        "time": 11,
        "roadType": 21,
        "categoryRoadType": 1,
        "facilityType": "11",
        "facilityName": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          126.92432912519702,
          37.55278308854395
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": 27,
        "pointIndex": 13,
        "name": "%EB%8F%84%EC%B0%A9",
        "description": "도착",
        "direction": "",
        "nearPoiName": "%EB%8F%84%EC%B0%A9",
        "nearPoiX": "0.0",
        "nearPoiY": "0.0",
        "intersectionName": "홍익대앞",
        "facilityType": "",
        "facilityName": "",
        "turnType": 201,
        "pointType": "EP"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to mapping this data in repositoryImpl but it won't work

Comment: Can you post a valid json response please?

Comment: sorry my bad
I repost it

                 And I used 'kotlin data class from Json' in android studio and get coordinates's type List<Any>

Comment: You are getting dynamic response, it is changing.Check out this link you'll find your answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279245/how-to-handle-dynamic-json-in-retrofit

Answer (score 0):

Dont process the JSONs manually. Use a site that converts a successful JSON response into multiple classes.
Best one I've found yet is https://json2kt.com. You will need to add `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` ontop of the data class and `@Json(name = "insert attribute name from JSON")` in front of each class attribute