# HttpURLConnection slow to disconnect - Java / Android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I want to get the file size of a file on a remote connection without actually downloading the (large) file. I am using the "Content-Length" header of the file. The relevant code is:

```
URL obj = new URL(FILES_URL + fileName);

String contentLength = "";
HttpURLConnection conn = null;

try {
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
    conn.setReadTimeout(3000);
    contentLength = conn.getHeaderField("Content-Length");
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    Log.d(TAG, "responseCode: " + responseCode);
} finally {
    Log.d(TAG, "pre-disconnect");
    if (conn!=null) conn.disconnect();
    Log.d(TAG, "post-disconnect");
}

return contentLength;
```

The command "conn.disconnect();" sometimes seems to take forever. I have seen 23 seconds! Admittedly, this is connecting to a secondary local device which is running a web server, but the WiFi signal is strong, relatively fast, and I have never had any such problems using "curl" from my laptop. I do not have control over the web server I am connecting too.

The problem possibly is enhanced when making multiple similar connections to different files one after another, not sure. This is, however, creating entirely new `HttpURLConnection`'s and not reusing the old one. Could reusing the connection help?

I never actually download the file or access the inputstream.

I could just not call disconnect, but I understand it is not recommended because resources would not be released. Is this not correct? I notice `URLConnection` doesn't have a disconnect. It is just suggested to close any streams you open.

This code is in an asynctask. I guess I could try moving the disconnect call itself to a further asynctask because I don't do anything afterwards. Not sure if that is even possible.

Do you have any suggestions? Should I try something other than `HttpURLConnection` to get the file size without downloading the file?

Comment: I suggest you change the request method to "HEAD". Otherwise you may be reading the entire GET response, i.e. the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to EJP in the comments. Changing the request method to "HEAD" made the disconnect almost instantaneous:

```
conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
```

From what I have read, `HttpURLConnection.disconnect()` will skip through the entire response object if it hasn't been read. Therefore, for very large files, it will take a long time. Using the request method "HEAD" force the response body to be empty and solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use either [Volley](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) or [Okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) for faster networking but depending on your requirement . Got through [Comparison Of Volley And OkHttp and Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley)  and decide which library to use.

As suggestion if you putting this code inside AsyncTask then Read [Dark Side of AsyncTask](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.in/2013/04/the-dark-side-of-asynctask.html).