# Android Asynctask vs loopj vs volley which one is better

Tags: android-asynctask, android-volley, loopj

I want to know which one is better to use android asynctask vs loopj vs volley

volley looks good but does not provide callbacks preexecute, onprogressupdate

also how is loopj is it better than volley

Comment: I think you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley?lq=1