# HTTP request library for android

Tags: android, json, android-volley, http-request, okhttp

I'm looking for a good HTTP library for my android app. I've been using `AsyncHTTP` by loopj (and I've only ever used that), but it's making my app crash when the network connection is lost. Also, it doesn't meet my requirements well. So far, I've found `okhttp` by Square and `volley` by Google. But I'm not sure which suits my purposes better. The following would be my requirements,

- Small frequent http request for JSON results
- JSON parsing
- Async operation with callback methods
- Caching, with functionality for force re-fetch

Some insights into how these differ and what I should be using, would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 3):

`OkHttp` is an HttpClient. If you want JSON parsing and callback methods you should use `Retrofit` which uses `OkHttp` internally. Both Retrofit and Volley are suitable for your requirements. `Volley` also has an image downloader in it but if you want image downloading when using `OkHttp` you need to use `Picasso` from square (which I suggest).

I personally suggest using `Retrofit`+`Picasso`. They are lightweight and perform really well and they have a decent documentation.

Comment: I've been using Picasso in my project as well, and it's awesome. I'll look into `Retrofit`. Thank you.
Can `Retrofit` also cache the requests? I'm avoiding going through the trouble to manage a local database. Is there even such a thing as HTTP caching, kinda like how `Picasso` caches the images?

Comment: @ShashwatBlack As long as I know you should handle the cache for http. You can take a look at this https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/5889518

Answer (score 0):

I personally used `Volley` for caching purpose, and `Picasso` for image downloading.

[RoboSpice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) is another library which will be useful for caching.

Check out bellow links to make final decision :

[Comparison of Android Networking Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16903205/3843374)

[Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

[RoboSpice vs Volley](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robospice/QwVCfY_glOQ)

Answer (score 0):

Combination of [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) and [Google Http Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/)/Spring/Retrofit (your choise) is what you are looking for. RoboSpice perform async requests by using one of this networking library with respect to Activity/Fragment lifecycle and also handle caching. JSON are parsed by this libraries.

Comment: I looked for some examples on `Robospice` - `Retrofit` combination, but I can't find much. I downloaded the [sample app](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/release/robospice-sample-retrofit) from the github repo, but neither do I understand it, nor can I run it. Could you direct me towards some basic tutorials for beginners, so I can get started?

Comment: Here https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki is wiki and here https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Starter-Guide is basic tutorial. Should help.