# Android networking library: Is it still worth using Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit, okhttp

This question is actually not about the coding, so I don't put any codes here.

While looking into the Volley library, I found out that some part of the APIs contain classes (e.g. classes of the org.apache.http packages) that are now deprecated in Android API level 22.

As I'm concerned about getting adjusted to the newest API environment, do you think it is still worth using Volley or would you recommend using other libraries such as OkHttp or Retrofit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the detailed response: 
[Comparison of Android networking libraries: OkHTTP, Retrofit, and Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley)

Personally, I went native to keep things simple and robust.  Using it for JSON responses and occasional images with no problem and I don't think they will deprecate HttpURLConnection anytime soon.