# Android Volley deprecated lib

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm making an android app using login / register. I found some tutorials and I wanted to know if android.volley (lib) is not deprecated.

Comment: Why would it be? More importantly, if it works, why does it matter? Deprecated doesn't necessarily mean something is bad.

Comment: I mean If I build a new app, it's always better to use last technologies ==> easier to maintain, easier to update.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472263/apache-http-client-removal-from-api23-will-that-have-an-effect-on-volley

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952152/android-networking-library-is-it-still-worth-using-volley

Comment: @cricket_007 deprecated says we have a better technology beyond that.so it's necessary to bounce for better performance right :)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things in Volley have been deprecated and replaced by new one's. I'm guessing you were trying to use ImageRequest with that tutorial. [Here](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/9aba4f5f861ab547751aa572c8559467dfa59270/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageRequest.java#L72) is the link to the new constructor for example at the time of my writing this.