# Volley+ OkHttpClient why use both?

Tags: android, android-volley, okhttp

Currently I am using in my app Volley+HttpUrlConnection as http client, but sometimes is a little slow and I can't cancell requests.

So looking for another client i find OkHttpClient, some people recommend this and (Retrofit), I am good with Volley and i dont think to change right now.

So my question is:

> What are the benefts using OkHttpClient with Volley? faster?

I have tried to find another OkHttpClient and all recommend this one.

Comment: I ve been wondering about this too, I ll be following the answers for this question, thanx for asking ^^

Comment: You are welcome. Actually i have implemented Volley and OkHttpClient, and i feel better, faster,such as major performance, cancelable aniwhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(from volley google i/o [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo)):

**In nutshell:**

**Volley** is:

- **Great** for rpc-tyle network operations that populate UI.
- **Fine** for background RPCs.
- **Terrible** for large payloads.

In Volley everything happens in the memory so that isn't great for large data downloading (such as a big image or streaming contents).

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley)