# Android Networking Libraries: LoopJ, Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, loopj

Whats is the difference between LoopJ and Retrofit?

For a small chat app Should I use Loopj or Retrofit? (Why)

Comment: Don't know about loopj. But a good discussion is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion Retrofit is very good for this kinds of applications.
I've used both in the past, but Retrofit was a little bit better.

Main differences:
It is very-very easy to implement
It has very good performance
I feel like everything is loading much faster using Retrofit