# List of libraries needed for http, REST API development in Android

Tags: android, rest, http

I am a newbie in developing web services for Android. I needed to know what are the list of libraries needed for http, REST API support in Android client along with their use case. It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Volley` networking library is the best which provides the concurrent request initiation and cancellation features. It has also documentation on https://developer.android.com/training/volley.

Further information on which library is best. Please go through the following links

- https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-library-to-make-HTTP-calls-from-Java-Android
- http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/
- [Comparison of Android networking libraries: OkHTTP, Retrofit, and Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the example for [Create a weather app on android](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-weather-app-on-android--cms-21587) where they take you through the steps of creating a client for a REST API.