# What is the most recommend way to consume web Service in android development?

Tags: android, web-services, android-studio, android-webservice

I am new in android development and getting start to consume web service. I want to do it in most latest recommended way. I found HttpUrlConnection is it the best and easy in most scenarios or any other Library?

Comment: please do some googling before asking here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-a-soap-web-service-on-android)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @tenten. First i googled around here and there then get confused about things thats why i am asking and looking for seniors recommendation.

Comment: Use Volley or Retrofit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparison of Android Networking Libraries: OkHTTP, Retrofit, Volley](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley)

Answer (score 1):

The basic one and i think the simplest is `Okhttp` but you have to understand that `Okhttp` is no more supported but still work when you downgrade your `SDKVersion` , the best solution is to use `Volley` or `Retrofit`.