# To connect with a web-service there is two options, either use a Library or "JSONParser" Class. Which is better? which one is safe?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-json, android-webservice

I am asking this because I am beginner in android development.

I am doing a core-banking application, so I used JSON Parser class to connect with REST Web-Service,

JSONParser Class is,

```
package com.anvinsolutions.digicob_custmate;
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JSONParser {
String charset = "UTF-8";
HttpURLConnection conn;
DataOutputStream wr;
StringBuilder result;// = new StringBuilder();
URL urlObj;
JSONObject jObj = null;
StringBuilder sbParams;
String paramsString;

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  HashMap<String, String> params) {

    sbParams = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    for (String key : params.keySet()) {
        try {
            if (i != 0){
                sbParams.append("&");
            }
            sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                    .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (method.equals("POST")) {
        // request method is POST
        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            conn.connect();

            paramsString = sbParams.toString();

            wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(method.equals("GET")){
        // request method is GET

        if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
            url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
        }

        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(false);

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    try {
        //Receive the response from the server
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        result = new StringBuilder(); // add this line
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }

        Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    conn.disconnect();

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON Object
    return jObj;
}
}
```

and i am confused if this method have any problem with Security,performance?
i didn't try any Libraries till now, i just used this JSONParaser Class. i think its easy to work with a JSONParser Class..

WHICH ONE TO USE?
thank you in advance! ;)

Comment: JSONParser is not the way to go.  Where did you get that?  I would not call that good code.

Comment: i got it from github.. but its working fine .. no problems till now.. but i don't know its safe or not!

Comment: What does this class if the web service doesn't return JSON?  Use an HttpClient, like the one from Apache.  This is the wrong way to go.

Comment: no, in our application we use only  JSON requests and response..

Comment: @duffymo Use of HttpClient is discouraged in Android. The custom Android HTTP Stack and other stuffs like OkHttp are optimized for mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never use JSonParser class to connect to a Web service. From your code, looks like you are using Vanilla HttpURLConnection class for connecting to service and using the JSonParser class to parse the result which is good and simple if you only have a couple of web requests to make in your application.

However since you said, it's banking application, you might have to think about scalability, multiple requests and stuffs like that. You could well try to handle them by yourself but the suggested way would be to use one of the tried and tested network libraries available for Android. Retrofit and Volley are two such and there are many more. The choice of the library to use is based on your use cases.

@AJay has already pointed to a page for comparison. Have a look.

Onto your next thing, about the parsing, performance is one of the key factors. Have a look at the below link for the options you have  - http://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/

I would say GSon is pretty good among all. We use it extensively in our in-house products.

Comment: As you said, actually i use some simple calls to Web Service for balance inquiry, cash deposit, transfer etc.. but as you all suggested to use library..  so i need to use a library.. i need to change all my code :( because i use this JSON Parser Class for all my requests and response :P :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use GsonParser by Google.https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: thank you :) oh its from google? so its safe for sure! am i right?

Comment: Yeah that's true. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use any of these 3 libraries they both are equally good in performance. Check this link, it will help you. Happy learning.

[Comparison of Android networking libraries: OkHTTP, Retrofit, and Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a deal with REST service, the easiest way is to use Retrofit library: https://square.github.io/retrofit/
With Retrofit you do not need to implement http calls and it automatically parses/creates json.

If you need more flexibility, I suggest using OkHttp library http://square.github.io/okhttp/, which is much simpler than pure HttpUrlConnection in combination with Gson lib https://github.com/google/gson for json parsing/creating.

Comment: OK, thank you.
I have a retrofit example code and i am dealing with REST Web-Service.