# Android Volley vs Retrofit. Which is better and why?

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley, retrofit

I want to make an application from scratch. Which third-party library should I use for parsing? I found two best library: Android Volley and Retrofit. Which should I use for better and fast response?

Comment: I personally prefer Retrofit in my apps. You can find a good comparison article here: http://vickychijwani.me/retrofit-vs-volley/

Comment: Even until i was beginner i did not used Volley, but changed my mind

Comment: i also find some link http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-volley-vs-retrofit-better-approach/

Comment: @VatsalHarde I don't want to -1 and also mark as duplicate but please delete this question because here is already same and more precise details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-and-volley/16903205#16903205