# Compiling 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' throws an error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley

I want to use Volley in my next project. So I imported it by adding

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

this line in build.gradle file.
But as soon as I sync the gradle again and try to run the app

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Could not open local class set analysis write cache (C:\Users\Vaibhav\AndroidStudioProjects\Volley.gradle\3.3\tasks_app_compileDebugJavaWithJavac\localClassSetAnalysis).
>   Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

this error comes up.I have tried every possible solution like

> deleting my .gradle folder,Building Clean Project,Invalidates/Caches Restart

[image]

This image shows the error as well as code

Comment: Always post your code and errors as TEXT, not as IMAGES.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use Volley in my next Android Project

Then use the non-[deprecated library](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

[Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: That too is not working...Getting the same error again.Is there any complete alternate way?

Comment: Your error indicates that you might not have permissions as your user to open the directory that gradle downloads folders. Did you ever run Android Studio as an Administrator?

Comment: I have already mentioned that deleting the .gradle folder is not working for me.@cricket_007

Comment: And no i haven't run Android Studio as Administrator.Is it helpful because I don't think that the error is caused due to not having the administrator rights.

Comment: Please can someone tell me a whole alternate way to do the same?I will be highly obliged.

Comment: Which grade folder are you deleting? There are two of them. Deleting both. If that isn't working, use a different version of Gradle. If Volley doesn't work, then use the different HTTP library

Comment: Different HTTP library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-and-volley

Comment: My point is that Volley works. I am using it in my projects, and this is the correct repository for it. I can't really tell what is wrong with your installation, but the error is `Unexpected lock protocol found`, and so it's a **Gradle** error, not a problem with Volley itself.

Comment: I just discovered that there is a jars-2.lock file in my .gradle folder.And it's not being deleted as it's saying "THE ACTION CANNOT BE COMPLETED BECAUSE THE FILE IS OPEN IN Open JDK Plaform Binary.Is there anything which can be done to that?

Comment: Reboot your computer? Stop all Java processes in the Task manager and delete the file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145770/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-cricket-007).