# create horizontal recyclerview in vertical recyclerview like google play store with volley

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I want create horizontal recyclerview inside vertical recyclerview like google play store and get data with volley and display, i see this sample http://android-pratap.blogspot.co.uk/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html
but not use volley for display data in recyclerview,**how to can used this API for display data in recyclerview horizontal recyclerview inside vertical recyclerview with volley**?
API:http://monaasoft.com/indianfm/api/test.json
Help me please

Data

```
public class Data {


private String title;
private List<Section> section;


public Data(){

}

public Data(String title,List<Section> sections){
    this.title=title;
    this.section=section;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public List<Section> getSection() {
    return section;
}

public void setSection(List<Section> section) {
    this.section = section;
}


 }
```

Section

```
public class Section {
private String name;
private String image;


public Section(){

}


public Section(String name,String image){
    this.name=name;
    this.image=image;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


 }
```

RecyclerViewDataAdapter

```
public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

private List<Data> dataList;
private Context mContext;

public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(Context context, List<Data> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.mContext = context;
}



@Override
public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = 
LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, 
null);
    ItemRowHolder mh = new ItemRowHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {

    final String sectionName = dataList.get(i).getTitle();

    List singleSectionItems = dataList.get(i).getSection();

    itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(sectionName);

    SectionListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new 
    SectionListDataAdapter(mContext, singleSectionItems);

    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);


    itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


   /*  itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setOnTouchListener(new 
    View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events once again.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
            // Handle RecyclerView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });*/

    itemRowHolder.btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "click event on more, 
    "+sectionName , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        }
    });







   /* Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.bg)
            .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != dataList ? dataList.size() : 0);
}

public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView itemTitle;

    protected RecyclerView recycler_view_list;

    protected Button btnMore;



    public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        this.itemTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        this.recycler_view_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
        this.btnMore= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMore);


    }

}

}
```

SectionListDataAdapter

```
public class SectionListDataAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionListDataAdapter.SingleItemRowHolder> {

private List<Section> itemsList;
private Context mContext;

public SectionListDataAdapter(Context context, List<Section> itemsList) {
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = 


 LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
.inflate(R.layout.list_single_card, 
  null);
    SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
    return mh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

    Section singleItem = itemsList.get(i);

    holder.tvTitle.setText(singleItem.getName());


    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(singleItem.getImage())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.itemImage);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
}

public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView tvTitle;

    protected ImageView itemImage;


    public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        this.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);


        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), tvTitle.getText(), 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }

}

  }
```

MainAcivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private RecyclerView my_recycler_view;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
List<Data> allSampleData;
private String TEST_URL="http://monaasoft.com/indianfm/api/test.json";



  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    allSampleData=new ArrayList<Data>();
    my_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    my_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);

    RecyclerViewDataAdapter adapter = new 
   RecyclerViewDataAdapter(MainActivity.this, allSampleData);

    my_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new 
  LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 
  false));

    my_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);



 JsonArrayRequest newreq=new JsonArrayRequest(TEST_URL, new 
 Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
@Override
  public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


     Log.d("main",""+response);





      for (int i=0 ; i<=response.length();i++){
        try {
            JSONObject sectionObj= (JSONObject) response.get(i);
            String title=sectionObj.getString("title");
            List<Section> sections=new ArrayList<Section>();


            JSONArray sectionArray=sectionObj.getJSONArray("section");
            for(int j=0;j<sectionArray.length();j++){
                JSONObject obj=(JSONObject) sectionArray.get(j);
                Section section = new Section();

                section.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                section.setImage(obj.getString("image"));
                sections.add(section);

                Data data= new Data();

                data.setTitle(title);
                data.setSection(sections);


                allSampleData.add(data);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


  }
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
   @Override
   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

   }
    });


     MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(newreq);

                }



        }
```

MySingleton

```
    public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = 
           Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should read some tutorials on how to use Volley.

http://www.infuy.com/blog/networking-for-android-made-easy-the-volley-library/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley

http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/

https://gist.github.com/ficusk/5474673

http://www.hackpundit.com/android-turorial-json-parse-volley/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo&feature=youtu.be

http://androidbackstage.blogspot.in/2014/05/android-developers-backstage-episode-8.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-weather-application-for-mars-using-volley--cms-23812

http://karn-neelmani.blogspot.in/2014/12/post-json-object-to-server-using-volley.html

http://mobilesiri.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-using-volley-networkimageview-android-studio/

http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-volley-imageloader-networkimageview-example

http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-volley-example/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJRjCurwXVw&index=30&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD

http://afzaln.com/volley/

https://plus.google.com/111851281564260689455/posts/ZxWapXmrqfF

http://blog.codeint.com/sending-custom-headers-with-volley-android-networking-library/

http://cypressnorth.com/mobile-application-development/setting-android-google-volley-imageloader-networkimageview/

https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/

http://narasimha-android.blogspot.in/2015/06/comparison-between-android-networking.html

http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/

https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/is-retrofit-faster-than-volley-the-answer-may-surprise-you-4379bc589d7c#.g7v2top6w

http://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put

https://www.sitepoint.com/volley-a-networking-library-for-android/

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/solving-the-android-image-loading-problem-volley-vs-picasso/

Comment: I used a lot of this volley but only can not use volley in  horizontal recyclerview inside vertical recyclerview!!

Comment: how can it be ? volley is just receiving data from network request you are sending there is no relation between it and recyclerview