# My Android app can't connect to server

Tags: java, android, read-data

I'm tying to read data from server I'm using xampp) but the data is empty
this is my connect activity:

```
public String link="";
public AsyncTaskConnect(String link){
    this.link=link;
}
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    try{
        URL url=new URL(link);
        URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            builder.append(line);
        }
        MainActivity.data=builder.toString();
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
    return "";
}
```

this is main activity:

```
public static String data="";
TextView txthello;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txthello=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txthello);
    new AsyncTaskConnect("http://192.168.1.2/digikala/test.php").execute();
    txthello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

but it doesn't work, what should I do?

Comment: the data in main activity dosen't have value

Comment: also link has no value

Comment: What does `execute()` do?  You call it, but your code isn't above.

Comment: no link has value I sent 192.168.1.2/digikala/test.php to link from main activity

Comment: I'm not sure but I think execute cause the link in main activity has sent to server

Comment: Public static data is not recommended https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a

Comment: have you made a internet permission in AndroidManifest?

Comment: yes I took Intenet permission

Answer (score 0):

Using [`HttpURLConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), it extends your `URLConnection` so I am changing just a little to your code. Given you have your query in the String variable `link`, this should work just as fine.

```
try {
                URL url = new URL(link);
                HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                Log.i(TAG, "POST Response Code: " + responseCode);

                //Takes data only if response from WebService is OK
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

                    //Stores input line by line in response
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

if you follow this snippet, response is the string which contains all of the response you get from your webservice, you can further convert it to JSON if you want.

Hope it works!

Comment: The documentation also recommends Volley

Comment: No, your answer is fine. It just isn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

> but the data is empty

Because execute is not a blocking call.

Assuming you can actually reach the server, `MainActivity.data` is an empty String until after the Asynctask onPostExecute

You can either use Volley, Okhttp, Retrofit, etc to simplify your networking code

[Comparison of Android networking libraries: OkHTTP, Retrofit, and Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-and-volley)

or add callbacks into your Asynctask

[How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

Comment: Tanks for all of your helps